# How to create a permanent "alias"?

Tags: command-line

If you create an alias for example:

```
alias cls="clear"
```

It exists untill you kill terminall session. When you start a new terminal window the alias doesn't exist any more. How to create "permanent" alias, one that exists in every terminal session?

Comment: As for this particular example, ^L (Control-l) clears the screen as well.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You can put such aliases in the `~/.bash_aliases` file.

That file is loaded by `~/.bashrc`. On Ubuntu 10.04, the following lines need to be uncommented to enable the use of `~/.bash_aliases`. On Ubuntu 11.04 and later, it's already enabled:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

The aliased command will be available on any new terminal. To have the aliased command on any existing terminal one need to source `~/.bashrc` from that terminal as,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: +1 I recommend this over editing ~/.bashrc. While indeed useful for a variety of other purposes, ~/.bashrc just has too many elements that could throw off a user who is unfamiliar with the peculiarities of Linux shells.

Comment: example: `echo "cls='clear'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: @ændrük I actually find the profusion of shell config files confusing. In my mind it is easier if there is one fairly long config file with all the settings.

Comment: @hobs it must be: `echo "alias cls='clear'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: gracias for the correction

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, putting the aliases in a `~/.bash_aliases` doesn't seem to work, but  there is this line instead: `test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true`. So it works if I put them in the `~/.alias` file!

Comment: ok so this topic is almost 7 years old now and I can't seem to find any recent answer like this. however it doesnt work for me anymore and asking now if something has changed

Comment: A correction in above comment that I can't edit `echo "alias cls='clear'" >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases`

Answer (score 48):

Add your line into `~/.bashrc` or into `~/.profile` / `~/.bash_profile` for remote logins.

If you want the command being executed for all users, put it into `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

**Edit:** In the latest versions of Ubuntu, `~/.bashrc` automatically sources `~/.bash_aliases`, so permanent aliases are best put into this file instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I wrote in ~/.bachrc

P.S. There is no ~/.profiles in my home directory.

Comment: .profile might be .bash_profile now

Comment: If the file in question does not exist, you can simply create it.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what's the difference between those two. (bashrc and bash_profile)

Comment: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html for the difference between ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 20):

You can add the function below to your .bashrc file.

```
function permalias () 
{ 
  alias "$*";
  echo alias "$*" >> ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

Then open a new terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` in your current terminal. You can now create permanent aliases by using the `permalias` command, for example `permalias cls=clear`.

Comment: Usage Note: when I typed `mkalias smount='sudo mount'` the quotes were not litterally echoed, so my solution was `mkalias "smount='sudo mount'"` If you are aliasing a 2+ word command you'll need this too.

Comment: I created a gist for this: https://gist.github.com/Masterxilo/f1967743fda3a1aded56ebaff4dd097b . Install permalias for the current user using `{ curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Masterxilo/f1967743fda3a1aded56ebaff4dd097b/raw/permalias | source /dev/stdin ; source ~/.bashrc ; }`

Comment: However, I created permfunction, a more powerful alternative https://gist.github.com/Masterxilo/29ac0df083827bbd45a7c8ddcf3936d7 which creates globally installed scripts on the PATH instead. These will be available to all open sessions immediately and are much more flexible. Install using `curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Masterxilo/29ac0df083827bbd45a7c8ddcf3936d7/raw/permfunction | sudo -E bash - ; hash -d permfunction &> /dev/null || true`

Answer (score 6):

See http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html for the difference between `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`

`~/.bashrc` is run every time you open a new terminal, whereas `~/.bash_profile` isn't. `~/.bashrc` contains the following, which includes the `~/.bash_aliases` file. This would be the most appropriate place to add your alias.

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Stick that command in the last line of your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Why not `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: bashrc is preferred, I understand, though not clear on why