# How can I create an alias so that when I enter "kt" it executes "killall gnome-terminal"?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, alias, symbolic-link

How can I create an alias so that when I enter "kt" it executes "killall gnome-terminal"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Creating an alias**

- To add an alias type the following in terminal,it will work until you close your terminal.
  `alias kt='killall gnome-panel'`
- To add this alias permanently you have to add the above command into .bashrc file
  `gedit ~/.bashrc`
- Add the first command at the end of your .bashrc file,
  [image]
- To refresh your .bashrc file type the following in terminal,
  `. ~/.bashrc`  or  `source .bashrc`
- Now you can type `kt` in terminal it will perform the action of `killall gnome-panel`
- To list all your aliases type `alias` in terminal.
  [image]

**Few examples:**

- To create an alias for update,you have to add the following to your `.bashrc`
  `alias update='sudo apt-get update'`
- For upgrade
  `alias upgrade='sudo apt-get upgrade'`
- To add both update and upgrade you can do the following
  `alias upd='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'`

**Note:**

- Source command is used for applying the changes that you have just made in a configuration file.
- By ændrük suggestion you can also put your custom aliases in ~/.bash_aliases

Comment: It would be cleaner to put custom aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`. Ubuntu's default `~/.bashrc` sources this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just type `alias kt="killall gnome-terminal"` in command line (I assume you're bash user).

To make this changes permanent, you can put this line to your `.bashrc`, for example. Execute `echo 'alias kt="killall gnome-terminal"' >> ~/.bashrc` (don't forget to re-apply changes using `. ~/.bashrc`)

Use simple `alias` command to see the list of aliases in action.

Cheers

update: BTW, you may find this useful as well: [Problem with creating permanent alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/problem-with-creating-permanent-alias)