# defining an alias is not recognized in other terminals

Tags: 20.04, bash, alias

I was playing around with the command "alias" and I noticed that when I define an alias for copy to be c ( alias c="copy" ) it only work on that terminal, if I switch to another one,  the command "c" won't be recognized as "copy" anymore.

Comment: This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/18787/how-can-i-create-an-alias-so-that-when-i-enter-kt-it-executes-killall-gnome-t

Answer (score 0):

`alias` is a bash builtin that changes the environment of your current shell, but it only changes in terminals created after the command was issued. To get the change to be recognized by others, run the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

also, it must be a bash terminal.