# Where is .bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I want to put new aliases to my `.bash_profile` file, but I cannot find this file.
Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's a hidden file, located in your home folder:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

(the `~` expands to your home directory. If your username is `user`, the result would be: `/home/user/.bash_profile`).

Since it's an hidden file, you have to make it visible.
To do it in Nautilus go to the "View" menu and check "Show hidden files" (or press the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).

If you are using Kubuntu with Dolphin, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to toggle the visibility of files.

Comment: The Keys Ctrl-H toggles the show/hide hidden files also.

Comment: sweet didn't know about that ctrl+H

Comment: `ls -al` shows hidden files if `ctrl -h` doesnt work

Answer (score 16):

`~/.bash_profile` is not the right place to put aliases and functions. They should go in `~/.bashrc`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles for an explanation.

Comment: yeah, does linux even automatically pull in ~/.bash_profile? I am not seeing it being pulled in automatically when opening a new terminal session

Comment: @AlexanderMills, the default when opening a terminal emulator is to run the shell in interactive mode (but not login mode), so .bash_profile is not read since bash only tries to read that in login mode. .bash_profile will be used when you log in via ssh or in a virtual console (ctrl+alt+f1-f6). When you log in graphically, there's no bash involved, so no .bash_profile is read, however, the graphical login process will run sh and have sh source .profile specifically, before execing the session (e.g. gnome-session). So environment variables set in .profile will be available in the session.

Answer (score 10):

**You do not usually have `.bash_profile` on Ubuntu, [nor should you](https://askubuntu.com/a/510723/22949) usually create that file.** As [jpezz says](https://askubuntu.com/a/969635/22949), it would be in your home directory on your Ubuntu system, which is what `~` stands for, and you can create it there. But if you do, you should be careful, because it will prevent [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) from automatically running the commands in `.profile`--which you almost certainly *do* have.

When `bash` [runs as a login shell](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/816), in WSL or otherwise<sup>**1**</sup>, it runs the first of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile` that exists in your home directory. If you have `bash`-specific commands that you want to run when you log in--but only when `bash` is your shell--you could put them in `.bash_profile`. But the mere existence of `.bash_profile` would prevent `.profile` from being used.

So then you would want to [*source*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing) `.profile` from `.bash_profile`, assuming you wanted those commands to be run too, which you almost always would. You could do that by putting this command in `.bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.profile
```

(Some readers may be accustomed to seeing that written as `. "$HOME/.profile"` when it appears in a startup script. That's always fine--and you may prefer to use that for commands that need to work on shells other than `bash` too, if you need to accommodate extremely old shells that don't support [standard features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01), which--well, you don't need that. In any case, `bash` always supports [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) and the point of `.bash_profile` is that only `bash` runs commands from it, so `. ~/.profile` is fine.)

The `.` builtin sources a file, which is to say it runs all the commands from the file in the current shell. Open an interactive `bash` shell and run `help .` for more information.

**The reason you don't usually have `.bash_profile` on Ubuntu even if you have `bash`-specific commands that you want to run on login** is that, by default, users' `.profile` files contain code that checks if the current shell is `bash`, then causes such commands to be run.

There is another answer to the question of where files like `.profile` or `.bash_profile` are. The default versions of these files exist in the `/etc/skel` directory. Files in that directory are copied into the Ubuntu home directories when user accounts are created on an Ubuntu system--including the user account you create as part of installing Ubuntu. If you look in that directory, you'll notice that there is a file called `.profile`--as well as some other files like `.bashrc`--but there is no file called `.bash_profile`. That is why--or, really, *how*--no `.bash_profile` exists in your Ubuntu home directory unless you have created it yourself.

---

**Finally, you should *not* put aliases in `.profile` at all, nor is `.bash_profile` a good place for them,** as [geirha rightly says](https://askubuntu.com/a/29296/22949). This is because you will want your aliases to work in interactive shells whether or not they are login shells. Instead, define your aliases in `.bashrc` or, better, `.bash_aliases` (as [guest boeroe points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/397035/22949)), which the default `.bashrc` sources. See [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

The default `.profile` file will check if you are running a `bash` shell and source `.bashrc` if you are:

```bash
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Meanwhile the default `.bashrc` will quit at the top without doing anything if it runs in in a non-interactive shell, so commands in it won't run if it gets sourced by `.profile` in a *non-interactive* login shell and in other more obscure scenarios<sup>**2**</sup>:

```bash
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So if you **put aliases in `.bashrc` or in `.bash_aliases`**, you'll get them for interactive login shells (where `.profile` is used) as well as interactive non-login shells (where `.bashrc` is used). This is what you want. Just don't put anything above the interactivity check, unless you really, *really* know what you're doing.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> This answer was originally written for [a WSL-related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969632/where-is-bash-profile-located-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux), but that question has been closed as a duplicate and this answer applies fully here as well, so I've expanded a bit and posted it here instead.

<sup>**2**</sup> When `bash` detects that it is probably running as the initial shell of a remote login that is *not* a login shell--such as when you use [`ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html) to run a single command on a remote machine--it runs commands from `.bashrc`. (See [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the [GNU Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).)

Comment: Nice and comprehensive answer! So in a nutshell, is it okay to create `~/.bash_profile`, e.g., to [start a Docker daemon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375195/run-dockerd-as-a-background-on-wsl-ubuntu/1375982#1375982) and just append `. ~/.profiles` or should it be avoided?

Answer (score 5):

It is handy to put all your alias in `~/.bash_aliases` in the user home directory. That is what is suggested in the `~/.bashrc` file in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to chime in - that even files are hidden in viewer you can still open all of them if you just enter name of the file. For example, if you write in dolphin address bar /home/<user>/.bashrc it will open the file with default editor without toggling show/hide some files.

Other way is to just open your favorite editor and just type in the name of file.

I see that as most preferred way to handle hidden files as showing not showing just add to noise that can be avoided.

And aliases should go into .bashrc as **geirha** wrote.