# How to set JAVA PATH in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, environment-variables

So java -version give path not found. I have tried the following:
Edit:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `/etc/environment`

`bash.bashrc` files and add to them the following:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_15
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_15
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

In addition, I also manually added the java bin directory to PATH.

```
PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_15/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_15/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/games"
```

I have restarted my computer several times but I still get

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_15/bin/java -1
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

See if that works.

Read more about it at `man update-alternatives`

Comment: I've tried that already. Not working. Is it bad that I don't have admin rights under /usr/local even with sudo? I'm on a corporate network

Comment: If you don't have the rights, you should install to a path you do have rights to execute and add that path to your $HOME/.profile

For example if you create /bin folder in your $HOME, by default in Ubuntu it is added to you PATH.

But perhaps somebody better informed will help you here, sorry mate ;)

I wouldn't know what are your privileges and [corporate] network setup.

What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: btw. you should try and start with /usr/bin, not /usr/local/bin

Comment: I have an installation under usr/lib/jvm All paths point to that, but the system is still trying to find it under usr/local/java All I'm trying to do is run java

Comment: what happens if you do:

`cd /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_15/bin`

`./java`

also, what output do you get on:

`whereis java`
`which java`

Comment: is i'm in the bin and type ./java it is recognized. `java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/local/bin/java /usr/local/java /usr/share/java` and `/usr/local/bin/java`

Comment: type `/usr/bin/java -version` first  

you can try to symlink to whatever works, e.g. `ln -s /usr/bin/java $HOME/bin/java`. This is assuming that `./java` command worked for you. (I assume the one in /usr/bin did)

Comment: So I solved this by re-installing Ubuntu and asking my company to disconnect my computer from the central network. This way I have full admin rights on it.

Comment: Firstly, I wanted to thank you, as this worked for me. But I don't understand why this worked? If this is not so easy, is there some reference I could read?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Create a new file called `.bash_profile` in your home directory:

  ```
  vi .bash_profile
  ```
- Insert the following lines:

  ```
  #! /bin/bash
  clear

  JAVA_HOME=/home/anuradha/installs/jdk1.7.0_02
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
  JRE_HOME=/home/anuradha/installs/jdk1.7.0_02
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
  export JAVA_HOME
  export JRE_HOME
  export PATH
  ```
- Source the `.bash_profile`.
- Check the java version by running `java -version`.

Note: for the Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit version you need the JDK 64-bit environment.

Comment: Which directory should this be created in??

Comment: @IgorG. The `.bash_profile` file should be created in your home directory: see [Where is .bash_profile](http://askubuntu.com/a/29241) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you might double check if your JDK is x84 or x64. If the version is a wrong one, ubuntu then cannot read it and it will tells you "No such file or directory"