# Why I can not login after set the path envrionment variable

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

I am using the 12.04LST, and I am trying to install the oracle jdk7 manually.

Then I update the `/etc/environment` to set the `PATH` variable.

This is the original file content:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

And I update it as this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7"
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Then I make it work using:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Then I type `java` and `javac`, and it worked.

However after I reboot my computer, I was kept at the login screen.

Then I use `ctrl+alt+f2` to go the terminal.

And update the `/etc/envrionment` like this:

`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/emvrionment` to the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7"
```

Then I can login again.

Now I have two questions:

1. Why I can not login if I add the line `PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"` in `/etc/envirionment`?
2. Is variables set in `/etc/environment` is available for all the user?

Comment: This should help:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo

http://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting

Comment: In fact, it does not. It does not told why user can not login.

Comment: Same problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259350/how-to-set-java-path-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1). Try to update the alternatives rather to set environment variable. `sudo update-java-alternatives -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7....full path needed here` see if works (with `java` and `javac`) . Alternatively you can try to set the path directly to PATH (without create a new variable) `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7"`

Comment: I do not prefer this manner. Since I have to add all the commands like `java` `javac` and something else.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/environment` is not executed as a script but read as a configuration file, so no shell expansion is available, thus variables can't be read.

If you wan't to use variables, resort to use session-wide variables in `~/.pam_environment`.

#### Reference

- [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) on the *Ubuntu help community*

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I checked it - it must depends of PAM somehow, if write to /etc/environment this: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7/bin" and then source it, it will work fine and you'll be able to login