# Where is ~/.bash_profile located in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to access `~/.bash_profile` from Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) in Windows Subsystem for Linux I get the following error:

```
-bash: /home/<username>/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Where is it located and how do I edit it?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe it is just `.profile` and `.bashrc` that are in the home folder in WSL.

Comment: if it is not there and you want it ... you create it , add what you want to it and source it from somewhere (/etc/profile probably)

Comment: [You should probably *not* create `.bash_profile`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/969923/22949)

Comment: I am not sure, but I do not think this is a duplicate as the question is about bash on windows and I am not sure if the question is about finding .bashrc from withing bash (duplicate) or windows (different path with unique problems, see the link in my answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the man page for bash:

> By  default, it first reads and executes commands from the file > /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it
>   looks for  ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and ~/.profile,  in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists
>   and is readable.

So it exists in your home directory IF AND WHEN you create it and make it readable.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash subsystem

With the bash on windows the files are located at in the same location if you are running within the bash environment, ie `/home/user_name/.bashrc` .

Create the file , form bash, as suggested by Rinzwind if necessary.

---

## Windows

However, if you are looking at the files from windows, outside the bash subsystem, they are located at

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs
```

so ...

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs\home\username
```

Note: The windows user name may or may not be the same as your bash username, depends on how you set bash up I suppose.

Warning - Dont edit or modify files in your bash environment from windows, see this link:

[**DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)