# How do I make bash warn me when overwriting an existing file?

Tags: bash

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory. All i want is bash to warn me whenever I attempt to overwrite an existing while using `cp` or `mv`. I'd really appreciate some help. :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should use the interactive mode which makes sure you get a 'prompt before overwrite'

```
cp --interactive
mv --interactive
```

Or in short

```
cp -i
mv -i
```

Type `man cp` or `man mv` on your command line to find out more.

Comment: So i guess those to commands go as aliases in my .bashrc as well. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Indeed! You can append something like `alias rm='rm -i'` to your .bashrc or better your .bash_aliases. Read more in the post [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Comment: But i just thought of something. What about some of the scripts i've written. Will they use the aliased cp and mv or the normal one?

Comment: @Bolt64 It depends on where you put your alias definition, but usually it will use the normal one.

Answer (score 16):

You also want to put `set -o noclobber` in your .bashrc. This will raise an error if you try to overwrite an existing file by output redirection.

```
$ set -o noclobber
$ echo one > afile
$ echo two > afile
bash: afile: cannot overwrite existing file
```

You can force the redirection to work with special syntax:

```
$ echo two >| afile
$ cat afile
two
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output