# How can I execute scripts as root without pointing to its location?

Tags: bash, permissions, root

I tend to use `sudo arp-scan --localnet --interface wlan0` a lot, but I find it cumbersome to type this each time. To speed things up, I've created a script, called `arp-lw-scan`, which should do this for me.

Contents of `~/Scripts/arp-lw-scan`:

```
#!/bin/bash
arp-scan --localnet --interface wlan0
```

I've added `~/Scripts` to my `$PATH` in `~/.profile`, so each script in that folder can get executed from any location by just typing its name in the terminal.

However, I'm having trouble executing `arp-lw-scan` in an easy way, because it requires root access. Just typing `arp-lw-scan` while being in my home directory gives an error about not having root rights.  I can type `sudo ~/Scripts/arp-lw-scan`, and that works, but that's still pretty much to type. I want to be able to just type `sudo arp-lw-scan` to execute the given script.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using [Bash aliases](http://askubuntu.com/q/17536/88802)? And why don't you put `sudo` in the single lined script there?

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea. Convert this comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that if you created `~/bin` directory instead of `~/Scripts`, it would've been added to PATH automatically, no need to modify `~.profile`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bash aliases

Aliases are the shortcuts in the command line. The regular shell, Bash, allows you to create your own aliases.

To try it out (without saving them permanently), try this:

```
alias myalias='gksudo gparted'
myalias
```

To save them permanently, create a file `~/.bash_aliases` like this:

```
alias myalias='gksudo gparted'
alias edsources='gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

The default `~/.bashrc` file installed for users in Ubuntu will source the `~/.bash_aliases` file by default.

Aliases allow you to append more arguments and 'overrule' current commands too. A common use case of this is

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

To get a confirmation message for everything you try to delete with `rm`.

In case you want to 'escape' an alias by running the original command, prepend it with a backslash. So, with the `rm` example, just do

```
\rm myfile
```

to remove the file without the `-i` option forced by the alias.

#### Current script

About your current approach, you should just be able to prepend the command in the one-line script with `sudo` (or `gksudo`).