# Custom command to open VLC with some options

Tags: bash, scripts, customization, vlc

I am trying to create a script to run vlc to play (or queue if a playlist is already present) some videos.

so far in my ~/bin/ folder I have created a file ``myvlc'' with the following command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vlc --http-port 54444 %U
```

This works as a command if I set it as launcher command in an icon, but it doesnt work if from the command line I type: myvlc ~/Videos/Some\ Folder/video.avi

How can I modify this bash script and make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Suggestion: use Bash aliases

Aliases allow you to append more arguments and 'overrule' current commands too. For example, this alias:

```
alias hvlc='vlc --http-port 54444'
```

will make

```
hvlc -v /path/to/my/movie.mkv
```

to become

```
vlc --http-port 54444 -v /path/to/my/movie.mkv
```

If you like the alias, install it permanently:

```
echo "alias hvlc='vlc --http-port 54444'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

The default `~/.bashrc` file installed for users in Ubuntu will source the `~/.bash_aliases` file by default.

*More about aliases in [an earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/244823/88802) of me.*

#### About your script

It's not passing the arguments to the `vlc` command as given to the "parent" Bash script. To fix this, make the line

```
vlc --http-port 54444 $@
```

The `$@` is the Bash magic for "all arguments". The `%U` is only used in `.desktop` files in GUIs and is a magic string to place the URL to be opened.

Comment: thanks your answer has been really helpful! Since you were kind enough to send me a link for aliases, do you have any clear tutorial for bash scripting as well?

Comment: ok the script works fine now thanks! Now how can I make it the default to be used when opening a video file?