# Problems with sudo inside shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc

I want to make a shell script to run VI with sudo if I try to edit a file that I don't have write permissions and for that I created an alias

```
    alias vi=my_script.sh

    #!/bin/bash
    file=$1

    if [ -r $file ]
    then
       /usr/bin/vi $file
    else
       sudo /usr/bin/vi $file
    fi
```

However, no matter what, when try to edit, let's say /etc/hosts, I still not being allowed to edit it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your script to work

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
wown=$(/bin/ls -alF $file | awk '{print $3}')

if [ -r $file ] && [ $wown == $USER ]
then
    /usr/bin/vi $file
else
    sudo /usr/bin/vi $file
fi
```

And if you wish to access it directly from anywhere, you can put it in PATH (like `~/bin/`) rather than making an alias for it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok assuming the bit in grey is your `my_script.sh` there are a few issues. First, the alias needs to be set in your `.bashrc` not in the file. [More detail is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/17538/139634).

Now onto the script the `-r` test checks if the file is readable not if it is editable. You probably have read but not write permissions. So you should try

```
#! /bin/bash

if test -w $1 
then
   /usr/bin/vi $1
else
   sudo /usr/bin/vi $1
fi
```

This should work. One tip I would add is that if you are having a problem with a bash script: Cover it in echo statements! One at the start to check it opens, one in each side of the the `if` statement to see where it goes.

Comment: it is also a nice approach.