# Volume via command line in 12.04

Tags: sound

I need to allow several clients to affect the volume of a central server.

Can I change the audio master volume via command line in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Do you expect them to do that concurrently?

Answer (score 4):

```
pactl -h
```

I just tried parameters like

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 12000
```

To mute

```
pactl set-sink-mute 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

[Amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer) is a great tool..

```
amixer set Master playback 5+
```

or

```
amixer set Master playback 5-
```

Answer (score 2):

Type `alsamixer`:
[image]

This can be used to adjust both input and output volume levels.

---

***Edit:*** As you seem to be displeased at my simple solution, I will add this:

Create a file in the home directory called `volume`:

```
gedit ~/volume
```

Then add these lines to it:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "down" ]; then
    amixer set Master playback 5-;
    echo "";
    echo "Turned volume down a bit";
elif [ "$1" = "mute" ]; then
    amixer set Master playback 0%;
    echo "";
    echo "Muted";
else
    amixer set Master playback 5+;
    echo "";
    echo "Turned volume up a bit";
fi
exit
```

Save and exit, then run this to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/volume
```

You should then be able to control it with:

- `~/volume`, `~/volume up`, `~/volume anything you like` - turn the volume up
- `~/volume down` - turn the volume down
- `~/volume mute` - mute

This will needed to be to added to the home directory of each user, unless...

```
sudo mv ~/volume /usr/bin/volume
```

This will add the script file to the `/usr/bin` directory, which means it can be executed with just this, by every user on the system:

```
volume
```

and the command line options will still work, for example:

```
volume down
```

<sub>**Note:** For those thinking you can create and [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) with is, it seems you can't as it does not tolerate command line options, so will only urn the volume up *(in this script anyway)*</sub>

Comment: that brings up a mixer, not affects the volume directly

Comment: Still works, @MildFuzz ;-)

Comment: not in the way I asked

Comment: Well, I thought that you do get the commands that others have suggested as answers, but they are faitly long and annoying - whereas using `alsamixer`, then using the arrow keys, it much similar and more intuitive. Though I have had an idea...