# How to stop playing music when remove headphones?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, music, headphones

I'm asking for any solution (algorithm, program installation ...) to get music stopping when we remove headphones,

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

It happens by default , as ubuntu 14.04 have different profiles for your headphone and your speaker. Just mute your speaker first and then insert your headphones, it will activate headphone profile and you can listen music, the moment you remove your headphone it will go back to speaker profile which was initially muted, so it will be muted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it has a 1sec delay. As I couldn't find any system event that triggered with the remove of headphones plug, so I used 1sec delay loop.

1. Check for sink ID and port names using:

   ```
   pactl list sinks
   ```
2. Then change them in this script that monitor port state then send MPRIS pause command:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   sink_id=1
   port_name_headset=analog-output-headphones
   port_name_speaker=analog-output-speaker


   while sleep 1 ;
   do
       cur_port=`pactl list sinks | awk '/Active Port:/ { print $3 }' | awk NR==$(( $sink_id + 1 ))`
       echo -n -e "\n was $prev_port now $cur_port"
       if [[ "$prev_port" = "$port_name_headset" && "$cur_port" = "$port_name_speaker" ]]
       then
           echo "  << Pause >>"
           gdbus call --session \
               --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance$(pgrep vlc) \
               --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
               --method org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
       fi
       prev_port=$cur_port
   done
   ```

**Note:**

- This is only for VLC but it could be modified to cover other MPRIS players. See [How do I stop xscreensaver during movies play?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445612/how-do-i-stop-xscreensaver-during-movies-play/446155#446155)

  Reference: [MPRIS D-Bus Interface Specification](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/index.html)
- If you mean just to mute sound, use this command (just change the `id`):

  ```
  pactl set-sink-mute id 1
  ```

  Reference: [Volume via command line in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404740/volume-via-command-line-in-12-04/404755#404755)