# Xampp Control Panel Can Not Launch

Tags: launcher, xampp

After searching all over the WWW, I couldn't solve my problem.
I want to launch Xampp via desktop control panel and also I made the `xampp-control-panel.desktop` in desktop and `~/.local/share/applications/` paths with the text below but no answer:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Name=Xampp Control Panel  
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP  
Exec=gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py  
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico  
Categories=Application;Development;Web  
Version=1.0  
Type=Application  
Terminal=0
```

I typed the command below:

```
gksudo python /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
```

the answer was:

```
Error importing pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade
```

and then I tried:

```
gksudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

and eventually when I click on xampp icon my administration password will be asked and when I type it nothing happens.

What can I do to get the control panel working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all the xampp folder is `/opt/lampp` so if you want to create some php files you need to put them in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. Don't use `var/www` or `var/www/html`

Now to start the [graphical interface](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html)

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux.run (or manager-linux-x64.run)
```

If you don't care about the graphical interface and you just want to run xampp then you do

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

To create an alias, open a terminal and type:

```
alias xampp='sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
```

and now every time you type `xampp` in the terminal, the graphical interface will start!

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I mean World Wide Web by typing WWW ;).  Is there anyway to make a shortcut for this control-panel? Best Regards

Comment: @HosseinSh I edited my answer to include the information you requested

Comment: @HosseinSh  to create a permanent shortcut http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** at first, open up the terminal and type the following to see if the folder exists or not.

```
 cd /opt/lampp
```

**Step 2:** if exists, then type ls to see the lists of files and folders

```
 ls
```

**Step 3:** look for a file `manager-linux.run` (or `manager-linux-x64.run`)

**Step 4:** type

```
 chmod +x xampp-linux.run
```

(if the    file name is `manager-linux.run`
otherwise type: `manager-linux-x64.run` as the file name suggests) to make the file executable.

**Step 5:** execute the file as a superuser.

```
 sudo ./manager-linux.run
```