# Quickly navigate from one path to another

Tags: command-line

I noticed that frequently I have to do something like this:

I am in a path: `/very/long/path/1` and I have to go to `/another/long/path/` to do some things there. Than I have to come back to my `/very/long/path/1`. To make things worse sometimes another third path is there and I constantly switch from one to another.

This is not a problem with `cd`, but is there a way of somehow store this paths and use them?

I am working from command line on some remote host.

Answer (score 4):

The [cdargs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cdargs) [image: Install cdargs] program is designed expressly for the purpose of managing bookmarks of frequently-visited directories for easy navigation in the shell exactly like you want. It comes with `bash` shell integration and tab completion on the directories that you have saved.

```
sudo apt-get install cdargs
. /usr/share/doc/cdargs/examples/cdargs-bash.sh
cd /very/long/path/1
mark path1
cd /another/long/path/
mark path2
cd /yet/another/third/long/path
mark foo
cv path1
cv foo
cv p<TAB> ## tab-completes to "path1/" or "path2/"
```

The bookmarks that you create are saved by `cdargs` in its own configuration file, so they are automatically carried over from one shell session to the next and available the next time you log in or open a terminal.

It even comes with an interactive curses mode to browse your complete list of bookmarked directories. Just run `cv` or `cdargs` with no arguments and it will show a list of bookmarked directory paths that you can select using the arrow keys or `vi`-style `hjkl`.

To activate `cdargs` for your shell environment automatically, simply source `/usr/share/doc/cdargs/examples/cdargs-bash.sh` from your `~/.bashrc` or otherwise arrange for it to be loaded in every `bash` interactive shell. For example,

```
cp /usr/share/doc/cdargs/examples/cdargs-bash.sh ~/.bashrc-cdargs
echo '. ~/.bashrc-cdargs' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the pushd and popd commands.  You can find information on Google but basically they are like cd with a stack like memory.

Comment: +1, and an example or little more explanation about pushd and popd commands would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You could always add an alias.

`alias big='cd /very/long/directory/goes/here'`

Then just type `big`

For more permanent alias:

[How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

---

Since the pushd and popd example got more upvotes, but the guy didn't explain it :)

Basically when you do pushd it makes a list of directories you can put into it. (If you have any programming background, it is very similar when you pop an item from a list, if not I will explain)

So if you do `pushd ~/Music` you just added a directory to a list from which you can access. You can also do `pushd dir` to add your current(working) directory to this list. When you use the `pushd` command alone, it will cycle through the list (it is actually technically stack).

### Example:

So if you want to add 3 directories. It would look like this

`user@user: pushd /really/long/dir/1/`     <--User input

`/really/long/dir/1/`                  <---Output

`user@user: pushd /really/long/dir/2/
  /really/long/dir/1/ /really/long/dir/2/ 
user@user: pushd /really/long/dir/3/
  /really/long/dir/1/ /really/long/dir/2/ /really/long/dir/3/`

These will all be added like so. When you use `pushd` it will go to the next directory on the list, and push the first to the end. So the list would start 1,2,3 and go 2,3,1 --> 3,1,2 --> 1,2,3 .

---

`popd` deletes the directory at the front of the list, and moves you to the first directory of the new list. So lets do this with 4 directories.(assuming popd command is used each time)

### Example:

(start with 1,2,3,4, in any directory)

2,3,4 (You are in directory 2)

3,4 (You are in directory 3

4 (You are in directory 4)

Empty list (No change of directory)

Comment: sounds cool. Is there a way to see a list of all aliases created in the system?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Just type `alias` and you'll see the active aliases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cd -` to swith to last visited directory. It will save you a lot of time.