# Vim installation in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, vim

I am unable to install Vim and need help.  I've tried the following:

```
root@cbitlab1:/home/cbitlib1# sudo -s
root@cbitlab1:/home/cbitlib1# apt-get install vim
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package ‘vim’ has no installation candidate
```

How do I fix this - I'm on 14.04.

Answer (score 51):

To make sure you have the latest sources.list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 13):

`Vim` is pre-installed in Linux based OS. For Ubuntu its minimal version is pre-installed.

```
vim.tiny
```

You can create alias to run it as vim

```
alias vim=vim.tiny
```

To make that alias permanent,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add `alias vim=vim.tiny` line in `.bashrc` file.

For more see here: [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)