# Can i edit a bash shell command?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I just wants to modify a bash shell command like exit so when i write exit in the terminal it clears the screen, and echo some text, wait 2 seconds, then execute the exit function.
So is there any way to modify a shell command on Ubuntu, if there is away how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *shell alias*

```
alias exit='clear; sleep 2; exit'
```

To make it permanent, add the alias to the bottom of the ~/.bashrc file.
see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) thread for help

Comment: isn't this going to override the original exit command, i mean that making exit='sleep 2; exit' the second exit is not going to be known for the bash and the terminal will not do the exit function.(i ask before do it and then find out that it is not going to work)

Comment: @Naruto no that shouldn't happen: in fact, you probably already have several such aliases already defined by your default `~/.bashrc` file, such as `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` and `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` (type `alias` without any arguments to see a list of the current ones).

Comment: @Naruto - the problem here is that `exit` is a bash builtin - for a normal command where you wanted it to do something similar you probably could enter the command's full path (e.g. `alias firefox='clear; sleep 2; /usr/bin/firefox'`). The above may work anyway :). An alternative to `exit` that may work would be something along the lines of `kill -SIGINT $$`, `kill -SIGKILL $$` to kill the process's PID (`SIGKILL` works but does not exit cleanly, other stuff seems to get ignored by the terminal - stuff on signals here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

Comment: can i revert this command to get the original exit command back,
also can i make another command the same way you answer here like (alias exit2='clear; sleep 2; exit') or how to do it ?

Comment: You can reverse it in the current shell using the `unalias` command e.g. `unalias exit`. You can execute the original command *without* unaliasing by preceding the command with a backslash, i.e. `\exit`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround instead of editing the exit bash command,
`trap 'clear; ~/ascii3.sh; spd-say "Exit"; sleep 2' EXIT`
by using a trap to the exit in the terminal and i put it in the end of the .pashrc file and it works.
And the ascii3.sh:

```
echo -e "\033[01;31m"
echo " _  _   __   _  _  ____     __     __ _  __  ___  ____    ____   __   _  _  _   "
echo "/ )( \ / _\ / )( \(  __)   / _\   (  ( \(  )/ __)(  __)  (    \ / _\ ( \/ )/ \  "
echo ") __ (/    \\\ \/ / ) _)   /    \  /    / )(( (__  ) _)    ) D (/    \ )  / \_/  "
echo "\_)(_/\_/\_/ \__/ (____)  \_/\_/  \_)__)(__)\___)(____)  (____/\_/\_/(__/  (_)  "
```

I think the question i asked was a very bad one as it didn't reflect my thoughts but i won't change it nor the answer i just put this answer here for anyone who want it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily modify a command, but you can replace a command.

```
# You only need this one time:
mkdir --mode=755 $HOME/bin  

# You need this command once per login (or in $HOME/.bashrc)
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Then any executable file/script in `$HOME/bin` will override any command with the same name.

When you type a command, the shell looks for an executable file by that name in each of the directories in `$PATH`.

Unfortunately, your example `exit` is a "Shell builtin" (see `man bash`) and is not sought along `$PATH`, rather it is handled by the shell internally. To override `exit` you will have to define a shell function or alias(see `man bash`) in your `$HOME/.bashrc`