# speech-dispatcher always stop working after terminal exit?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-to-speech

In a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604209/can-i-edit-a-bash-shell-command) I made this line:

```
trap 'clear; ~/ascii3.sh; spd-say "Exit"; sleep 2' EXIT
```

The content of ascii3.sh is:

```
echo -e "\033[01;31m"
echo " _  _   __   _  _  ____     __     __ _  __  ___  ____    ____   __   _  _  _   "
echo "/ )( \ / _\ / )( \(  __)   / _\   (  ( \(  )/ __)(  __)  (    \ / _\ ( \/ )/ \  "
echo ") __ (/    \\\ \/ / ) _)   /    \  /    / )(( (__  ) _)    ) D (/    \ )  / \_/  "
echo "\_)(_/\_/\_/ \__/ (____)  \_/\_/  \_)__)(__)\___)(____)  (____/\_/\_/(__/  (_)  "
```

and put it at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file, but every time I make the `exit` command or just quit the terminal by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or the ☒ mark in the GUI, the speech-dispatcher is no longer working just like I stopped it.

`Note`: i am working on Ubuntu 14.04, GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1), and i am using the default terminal on Ubuntu.

So what is going on please?

Comment: post the content of `~/ascii3.sh`

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the problem of mine but it is already found in the 2nd answer of the link in the 1st line of my question.

Comment: Can I exclude that in "ascii3.sh" nothing is included, which can have a negative impact? No. You want to be helped you.

Comment: Then are there any thing weired about the trap command?

Comment: Does it work if you run `spd-say foo` manually? What you describe works as expected on my system.

Comment: Manually before closing the terminal yes works, but after closing it it's not working at all(no sound given to me).

Comment: There's something different going on then. I tried and it worked as expected. Please [edit] your question and include your bash version, your terminal name and version, and how you're logging on to this machine. Are you sure your `.bashrc` is being read? Try adding a line like `foo="bar"` and then running `echo $foo`. Does it print `bar`?

Comment: ok i added them, and about what you say of testing the .bashrc file everything work just well.

Comment: There might be something strange in your `~/.bashrc` then. Could you show us the entire thing? Also, do you have anything in `~/.bash_logout`? Finally, I would also try with full paths, so `/usr/bin/spd-say` instead of `spd-say`.