# Create a file command to terminal

Tags: shortcuts

I have downloaded a program that does not need installation through the web;

How can i create a command for the terminal to open that specific command:

Example: open terminal, type unity-control-center to open system-settings

Comment: Move the executable to `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Should i move it, or copy it?

Comment: To run a program, just type its name, no need to create any commands.

Comment: the program is not an installed package, it is a folder i have in the desktop with a program inside

Comment: Try ~/Desktop/folder-name/program-name.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question goes like that: "How do I execute a downloaded program, which is not installed in the systems default executables directory?"

If you only want to use the program for a short period of time, simply mark it as executable with

```
chmod +x path/to/my-program
```

Now, you can run it with

```
path/to/my-program
```

Should your working directory be the one the program is inside, it doesn't suffice to write `program`. Instead, you have to do

```
./my-program
```

---

If you're gonna keep it, though, the most practicable thing to do is to install it manually by placing it in `/usr/local/bin`, the directory intended for executables not managed by the package manager.

Move or copy the executable there using

```
sudo mv /path/to/my-program /usr/local/bin/ # or sudo cp...
```

Also ensure the file is marked as executable, which is normally not true when it was downloaded from somewhere:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my-program
```

---

Should the program come with any special libraries or resource files, things may become a bit more complicated. If you want to comply to standards, you should move those files to `/usr/local/share/my-program/`, else just move them to `/usr/local/bin`, too (and hope noone ever sees that except for you ☺ )

Now, your program may not find those files on its own. If this is true, you can create a launcher script, e.g. /usr/bin/local/start-my-program or whatever you like:

```
#!/bin/bash
env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/my-program/ /usr/local/bin/my-program
```

Also, make this one executable again with

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-my-program
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points :

1) That fine/binary has to be placed somewhere in your path. `echo $PATH` to know what folders are available. Preferably you'd place it in `/usr/bin` or create `bin` folder in your home folder, and [add that folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286) to your `$PATH`

2) The binary/executable must have permissions `-rwxr-xr-x` when you list it with `ls -l mybinary`. Use `chmod +x mybinary` to achieve that that.

3) Once binary is in folder that is part of your `$PATH` and is executable, there is a myriad of ways to run it. One, you can type it in terminal just like you wrote in your question, another way is to [create alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) to it; there's also an option to create a custom shortcut that will open the terminal and run that command. For that open System Settings -> Keyboard -> shortcuts tab -> Custom -> click + sign, and name it whatever you want; for command , write `gnome-terminal -e /path/to/your/binary` or `xterm -hold -e /path/to/your/binary`