# How to execute a program from symlink

Tags: executable, symbolic-link

I have the following go program that runs with:

```
 ./hack/go/bin/wego
```

How can I create a symlink to run this program with the command `weather`?

Comment: @heemayl he wants a bash alias.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: @Tim he can achieve the same with a symlink, and won't need a bash alias to execute (you can create symlinks with different names on the link, and it'll execute the actual thing it's linked to)

Comment: @Tim probably..i might have fallen for the literal wording :)

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo ln -s /whole/path/to/script.extension /bin/weather
```

This will create a symlink into the /bin/ folder, which is included in everyone's PATH.  If it requires sudo to run, I recommend placing it in `/sbin` instead of `/bin`.

Comment: It's more of a cosmetic difference, but traditionally scripts that require elevated or superuser access go in sbin so they can be differentiated from scripts that do not require superuser access (those in bin).

Comment: I really have the same problem as before, maybe I need to be more clear. Is there a way I can type "weather" and omit "./" in "./weather" to run the program? This is the type of functionality I am looking for

Comment: If you symlink it Into /bin and log out then back in it should work without the ./. Once it is included in a directory in your PATH you won't need to specify the location

Comment: As an added note, you should probably use /usr/local/bin since it is a more canonical directory for user scripts