# Switch between multiple java versions

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, android-studio

While installing Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the message that my Java version (`javac 1.7.0_79`) is causing problems. I found a [solution](https://youtu.be/Yz2l-4GDpZE) of how to install a newer Oracle version of Java:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

However I'm afraid that this might overwrite my existing `open-jdk` version of Java. Since I don't know which of my programs depend on Java, I fear that this could crash these other programs.

Is there a way to make sure `apt-get` doesn't overwrite my previous Java? I would basically like to have installed both and be able to switch between them manually, depending on what version I need.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Apt-get won't overwrite the existing java versions.

To switch between installed java versions, use the `update-java-alternatives` command.

List all java versions:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

Set java version as default (needs root permissions):

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/java/version
```

...where `/path/to/java/version` is one of those listed by the previous command (e.g. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`).

---

Additional information:

`update-java-alternatives` is a convenience tool that uses Debian's [alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) (`update-alternatives`) to set a bunch of links to the specified java version (e.g. `java`, `javac`, ...).

Comment: For me this caused java -version to be java8, but JAVA_HOME was still set to 7 :(

Comment: tq this solve my problem too. @Nenotlep what I did is edit the environment variable manually either in .bashrc or /etc/environment

Comment: `update-java-alternatives` wasn't available for me. I just replaced that command with `update-alternatives java`.

Comment: @nofinator that only affects the `java` executable. Which Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: @Nenotlep in order to change `JAVA_HOME` you have to run the following command:

`source /etc/environment`

Comment: @janb you should edit this answer, as above won't work without your additional input.

Comment: @janb I honestly don't understand why this would have any effect unless you manually specified `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`. I just switched back and forth between java 8 and 11, and there is still no `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`. In fact, it is set nowhere in my environment. I therefor rejected the suggested edit. If there are circumstances in which the suggested command is needed, please suggest a new edit and explain when and why it would be necessary.

Comment: My `$JAVA_HOME` is unaffected by any of the proposed commands, too. My `~/.bashrc` has a line `export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")` though and that does the trick for me: `source ~/.bashrc`. If your `~/.bashrc` doesn't have that line, run directly `export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:bin/javac::")`.

Comment: This easily did the work in my PopOS! Thanks a lot @danzel

Answer (score 151):

Use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

which lists all installed versions with current active one marked and provides dialog to switch:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path...
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java...
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java...
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java...
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java...

Press <enter> to keep...[*], or type selection number:
```

Use

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"
```

to set `$JAVA_HOME` from current active version

Comment: As noted by @danzel at the accepted answer, this affects only the `java` executable, not the other parts of the configuration.  Use `update-java-alternatives` if available.

Comment: Using this command, you have to update each of java, javac & jrunscript separately.

Answer (score 20):

## Configuring Java

You can configure which version is the default for use in the command line by using `update-alternatives`, which manages which symbolic links are used for different commands.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The output will look something like the following.

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          2         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          3         manual mode
  5            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              4         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

You can now choose the number to use as a default. This can also be done for other Java commands, such as the compiler (`javac`), the documentation generator (`javadoc`), the JAR signing tool (`jarsigner`), and more. You can use the following command, filling in the **command** you want to customize.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config command
```

## Setting the `JAVA_HOME` Environment Variable

Many programs, such as Java servers, use the JAVA_HOME environment variable to determine the Java installation location.

Copy the path from your preferred installation and then open /etc/environment using Sublime Text or your favourite text editor.

```
sudo subl /etc/environment
```

At the end of this file, add the following line, making sure to replace the highlighted path with your own copied path.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Save and exit the file, and reload it: `source /etc/environment`.
You can now test whether the environment variable has been set by executing the following command: `echo $JAVA_HOME`. This will return the path you just set.

Comment: This doesn't change the version of the java compiler `javac`

Answer (score 11):

Based on the answer from @muet, I found this to work seamlessly:

Add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"
```

Add to aliases:

```
alias useJava8='yes | sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default && source ~/.bashrc'
alias useJava7='yes | sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default && source ~/.bashrc'
```

Then you can switch within the same shell using only: `useJava7`or `useJava8`

Comment: to make aliases permanent one can put them in ~/.bashrc , more info here https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: E: Unable to locate package oracle-java7-set-default

Comment: The unequivocally easiest way to install, use, and switch between different java versions is using SDKMAN!

See here: http://sdkman.io/usage.html

Comment: recently come across another command to set the JAVA_HOME, yet to try on `.bashrc`: `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))`

Comment: oracle-java package does not exist. Use openjdk-8-jdk https://docs.datastax.com/en/jdk-install/doc/jdk-install/installOpenJdkDeb.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider also using the GUI tool `galternatives` available through the ubuntu package manager.

Answer (score 0):

`jrunscript`may not be available in future releases, so safe choice is using
 `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))` as suggested by @ThiamTeck.
Also `.bashrc` needs to be executed every time you change your java version using `update-alternative` command.