# How can install openjdk7 on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: java

I need install openjdk7 on ubuntu 17.10 I tried install using this repository but doesn't work 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu' any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Java 7 in 16.04 and using multiple Java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990951/installing-java-7-in-16-04-and-using-multiple-java-versions)

Comment: Leo Cardona : Your link tells that the latest supported version is Ubuntu 16.04 : `dist/xenial`.