# How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?

Tags: 18.04, jdk

I upgrade my system to ubuntu 18.04 lts, but I work on projects that require JDK 7.
How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?

Answer (score 35):

***Download the JDK for Linux 32-bit or 64-bit (for example: `jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz`)***

1. Navigate to `~/Downloads`:

   ```
   cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
   ```
2. Create a a directory in `/usr/local` where `java` will reside and copy tarball there:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
   sudo cp -r jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java/
   ```
3. Navigate to `/usr/local/java`:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/java
   ```
4. Extract the tarball:

   ```
   sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```
5. Check if tarball has been successfully extracted:

   ```
   ls –a
   ```

   You should see `jdk1.7.0_80`.
6. Open `/etc/profile` with `sudo` privileges:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/profile
   ```
7. Scroll down to the end of the file using arrow keys and add the following lines below at the end of `/etc/profile` file:

   ```
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80
    JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80 
    PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

    export JAVA_HOME
    export JRE_HOME
    export PATH
   ```
8. Update alternatives:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaws" 1
   sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java
   sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac
   sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaws
   ```
9. Reload profile:

   ```
   source /etc/profile
   ```
10. Verify installation:

    ```
    java -version
    ```

    You should receive a message which displays:

    ```
    java version "1.7.0_80"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
    ```

Comment: Thank you, i used your instructions to install JDK8 and it worked well. Thanks! A few minor points though: If i try to download JDK7 it wants me to log in to an Oracle account. Also steps 8-14 are only needed if the user already has Java installed

Comment: @sana wow that is a high quality answer!

Comment: I think the export mush be `export JAVA_HOME`

Comment: This does not install *OpenJDK*, it installs Oracle's JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Update -

Since the bottom fix is no longer working, try this -

1. Visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html
2. Download the desired java package. i.e, 32bit(x86) or 64bit(x86_64) 

   **note**: you'll need to sign in to download it as pointed by @Kendzi in the comment below
3. Change location to your downloads folder(or to where you've download the archive) 

   `cd ~/Downloads`
4. Extract the archive

   `tar -xvzf jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz`
5. There should be a new folder available now, named - **jdk1.7.0_80** or something similar
6. Move the folder to a desired location.
   Move it to the default location(recommended) - 

   `sudo mv jdk1.7.0_80 /usr/lib/jvm/`

   **note** : create the **jvm** folder if it does not exist with `sudo mkdir /user/lib/jvm`
7. Assuming the folder has now been moved to **/usr/lib/jvm**,

   1. If this is the absolute first time you're installing Java, just run the **update-alternatives** command to update the preferred Java as default

      `update-alternatives --config java`

      and select the option number for Java 7
   2. if you have already installed Java once check whether a symlink exists in **/etc/alternatives** 

      `sudo ls -al /etc/alternatives/java`


      If you see a listing similar to the following

      `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jun 20 21:51 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`


      The symlink exists and only needs to be updated using the command -

      `update-alternatives --config java`


      This will list the available Java executable files available in your system, like so -

      (including the JDK 7 executable you've placed in **/usr/lib/jvm**)
      [image: Java - update-alternatives --config java]
      Note the asterisk(*) next to option 1. This indicates the default version of Java being used.

      If the JDK 7 location is listed here, enter the option number and hit enter to set JDK 7 as the default.
   3. If for some reason no listing is provided after running the **update-alternatives** command, check if the symbolic links(symlink) are setup properly

      `sudo ls -al /etc/alternatives/java`


      if no file is found, create the symlink -

      `sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java`


      Also, create a symlink in **/usr/bin** to ensure availability of the Java executable in the terminal.
      So first check if the file exists in **/usr/local**- 

      `sudo ls -al /usr/bin/java`

      if no file is found, create the symlink -

      `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java`
8. Finally set the JAVA_HOME variable for application use by editing file **/etc/environment** 

   `sudo gedit /etc/environment`


   and add the JAVA_HOME variable like so -

   `JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"`

   save and close the file.

   Reload the environment file using command -

   `source /etc/environment`

---

**(Fix is no longer working as noted by @Christian Rodriguez)**

After downloading the the Oracle JDK 7 package from Oracle's website, place the file in the location -

`/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/<Oracle JDK 7>`

(create the `oracle-jdk7-installer` folder if it is not already present)

Then open a terminal(shortcut: `Ctrl+Alt+t`) and execute each of the following commands(one after the other) -

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To verify the installation was successful, execute the following command -

```
    java -version
```

You should see a message similar to the one shown below -

```
    java version "1.7.0_76"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Refer

1. http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
2. http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

for more information.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer working :|

Answer (score 0):

Looks like regular JDK are only available to Oracle Customers after creating account:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html
```

But that link is still working:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-jdk-7u21-downloads-1956231.html
```

Simply chose "java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh" and install it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . but how can i install it ?

Comment: - mark it as executable `chmod +x java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh` and run it by `./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh` that run UI with wizzard

Comment: I am a new Ubuntu user. how can i mark it executable ?

Comment: You need to open terminal, go to directory where you downloaded file and execute command: `chmod +x java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh` later run install with executing second command `./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh`

Comment: when i run  ../java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-linux-x64.sh  i get the folloing error :Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 7 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME