# How to install openjdk 7 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, openjdk

Today I try to install openjdk 7 on my ubuntu 18.04 system. It always install oracle-java8-installer instead openjdk 7. Please help me

apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Comment: Ubuntu has removed JDK 7 from the repository. Also, it is no longer supported for any further updates. So you better install jdk8.

Comment: If you still want it you can download from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want to install openjdk, not Oracle jdk

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate if the suggested answer applies to a different version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Here you got a [very good answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034387/how-can-i-install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-64bit) with a step-by-step instruction:
Download it [here from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have installed OpenJDK 1.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

**Step 1. Install OpenJDK 1.7**

```
sudo dpkg -i https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjpeg62-turbo
sudo dpkg -i https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jre-headless
sudo dpkg -i https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jre
sudo dpkg -i https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jdk
```

**Step 2. Switch to OpenJDK 1.7**

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH
```

Note: If you want to use `javac` command instead of `openjdk 1.7`, use below command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: It returns error: dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjpeg62-turbo': No such file or directory
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jre-headless': No such file or directory
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jre': No such file or directory
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'https://packages.debian.org/experimental/openjdk-7-jdk': No such file or directory