# Need to install JDK 7.0 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, jdk

I was trying to install Jdk 1.7 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-7-jdk
```

But getting the below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate**
```

How Can I Overcome this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034387/how-can-i-install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-64bit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Java 7 in 16.04 and using multiple Java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990951/installing-java-7-in-16-04-and-using-multiple-java-versions)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer instead, so I do not post *several comments*.
This question has been asked several times before (see below).

The most useful answer seems to be [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034456/226614).

[How to install openjdk 7 on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053764/how-to-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-18-04)

[How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034387/how-can-i-install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-64bit)

[Installing Java 7 in 16.04 and using multiple Java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990951/installing-java-7-in-16-04-and-using-multiple-java-versions) (referred to 16.04, but useful)

https://openbravotutorial.wordpress.com/2019/05/11/install-openjdk-7-on-linuxmint-19-1-or-ubuntu-18-04/

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/9duojg/install_java_7_on_ubuntu_1804/