# Install Oracle java 7 along with Openjdk 1.8 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

I have openjdk version "1.8.0_191" in my system. I need Oracle Java 7 for my project. I tried to install with following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

But it is throwing the below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java7-installer is not available, but is referred to by 
another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java7-installer' has no installation candidate
```

How to install the both version in my system?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks all. The below answer helped me.
[How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034387/how-can-i-install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-64bit?newreg=c29ea3a31dfa4419b5ce9a650326e8f1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the oracle java installers by webupd8team have been discontinued as you can read [here](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)(java 8) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html)(java 6 and 7).

Back in the day, the java binaries were available for download for free without an account. Webupd8team's java installers downloaded them from oracle's server in the background.

Recently, oracle changed their license and now you need to login to an oracle account to download java 8. Therefore, the installer doesn't work anymore.

Java 6 and 7 are only available for oracle customers now. If you have an oracle support account (which is not free), please ask the oracle support how to obtain and install java 7.

Comment: Thanks. The below answer helped me. [How can i install jdk7 on ubuntu 18.04 lts 64bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034387/how-can-i-install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-64bit?newreg=c29ea3a31dfa4419b5ce9a650326e8f1)