# force Oracle java 10 not java 11

Tags: 18.04, java, oracle

the linux uprising ppa is currently forcing version 11 of java on us.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

that's nice I like modern and being up to speed, but I have an app that'll only run with java 10.

webUpD8 stopped after 9 and linux uprising started at 10 and that worked (apparently..., I personally never got to test it) until they released 11 and now when you type  :

```
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```

you get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java10-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java10-installer' has no installation candidate
```

only typing :

```
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

will work. that's the package that's being referenced above.

clearly something was done that was a little sloppy :

**what are my options?**

Comment: Java 10 is no longer supported. It reached EOL the moment when 11 was released in September 2018. That is why it is no longer really available and why you should not be using it anyway. Java 11 is supposed to be fully backwards-compatible, I believe, so anything running under 10 should work just fine with 11. See the table on https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html for reference about the EOL dates.

Comment: i tried running `sudo apt install openjdk-10-jdk` but even that defaulted to installing oracle jdk 11. is there really no trick I can pull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: If you have successfully installed openjdk-10-jdk package, than You just need to switch default jdk version using 'update-java-alternatives' command (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions)).

---

You could manually install openjdk (instead of using apt).

For example, openjdk 10 is available to download at [jdk.java.net](https://jdk.java.net/10/) or [adoptopenjdk.net](https://jdk.java.net/10/).

Installation instructions are available at [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-linux-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-737A84E4-2EFF-4D38-8E60-3E29D1B884B8).

Comment: thanks that worked to get java 10! I ended using this guide instead (but with your link to the tarball) : https://www.javahelps.com/2017/09/install-oracle-jdk-9-on-linux.html