# How to "install" multiple Java versions?

Tags: java, jdk

How do you have multiple Java versions in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

In my Windows, I usually have 3 versions available for development. I do not have them installed in my system but rather, I can switch to different versions when I need to by pointing to the right jdk in Environment Variables. How can you do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should search the forum a bit more first. Look here https://askubuntu.com/q/740757/557184

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check available versions with some search like:

```
apt --names-only search "openjdk-.*jre$"
```

Switch between versions with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```