# Uninstall JDK 12 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: package-management, jdk

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed JDK 12 from [this Linux Hint guide](https://linuxhint.com/install_jdk12_ubuntu_1904/).

However, I realise I need an earlier version of JDK for the program I want to run. How do I uninstall JDK 12?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "install" multiple Java versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110464/how-to-install-multiple-java-versions) and [Switch between multiple java versions](https://askubuntu.com/q/740757/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between multiple java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions)