# Unrecognized option: --version Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java

My system is ubuntu 16.04. First I had uninstalled java10 and then tried installing java8 so I am getting the below mentioned error. Please anyone can help me regarding this error with detailed steps.Please help soon its urgent.

Unrecognized option: --version Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Comment: Could you please show how you uninstaller Java 10 and how you installed Java 8? Without further details it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between multiple java versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are really typing:

```
java --version
```

If so, try with a single dash like:

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove /usr/lib/jvm , this will remove jdk from your system
2. Now again install using `sudo apt install default-jdk`
3. Check command java-version, and it shows current installed version.

This worked for me!