# Jenkins error "Incorrect Java version" for Java11. After removing Java11 and installing Java8. java is not found anywhere

Tags: 18.04, openjdk, jenkins

I tried to install latest stable Jenkins version which supports Java 11. So after installing Java 11(JDK) I got the error from Jenkins that incorrect java version was found.

So uninstalled the Java 11 and tried to install Java 8. While installing java 8, the Jenkins messages `incorrect java version` repeatedly was coming. So I completely removed both Java 11(JDK) and Java 8(JDK) and made sure no folders are there in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib/jvm` for both java 11 and java 8. When I installed java 8 the system says JDK 8 installed but im not able to find any java version in my system. Why?

1. How to set up the JDK 8 for the Jenkins and make it working? Where to find java version?
2. How to remove Jenkins completely from the system if I need to install everything from scratch? Or any way to reset the Linux to a previous state (before java and Jenkins installed)
3. How to have/maintain both JDK8 and JDK11 in the system?

Answer (score 33):

I've just encountered this problem, and it actually looks like an issue in `/etc/init.d/jenkins` testing for the Java version. I just posted a solution here: https://dorian.fraser-moore.com/works/5054500/ubuntu-and-jenkins-found-an-incorrect-java-version , sharing below for those who find this question as first google hit.

Following a recent update to my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS dev server my installation of Jenkins stopped running on boot. Checking `systemctl status jenkins.service` returned back this set of messages

```
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038744]: Found an incorrect Java version
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038744]: Java version found:
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038776]: openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038776]: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038776]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
Nov 13 09:35:43 tattve jenkins[1038744]: Aborting
```

Which seemed odd, as jenkins support Java 11 and openJDK, indeed I'd been running that before.

Digging around a bit I noticed the init script in `/etc/init.d/jenkins` that the script, at lines 56-60, was using SED to extract the version from the java - version command into a numeric value, but the regular expression was a bit to broad

```
# Which Java versions can be used to run Jenkins
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "18" "110" )
# Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
```

It turns out this last line was setting JAVA_VERSION to 11.09 which doesn't match anything in JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSION. I could add 11.09 to JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS to make it run, but a better fix seem to be to fix that permissive sed line. Changing it to:

```
JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
```

Did the job. It might help someone else.

[Due Diligence Edit]

It looks like someone has already made a PR for a fix: https://github.com/jenkinsci/packaging/pull/198

Comment: This was exactly the issue on my server. It did help for me :) Thanks.

Comment: run `systemctl daemon-reload` 
and `sudo service jenkins start` after changing the jenkins startup script

Answer (score 1):

### Jenkins required java version

Jenkins work [perfectly](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) with the Ubuntu provided `openjdk` packges. You can even decide which OpenJDK version you prefer:

```
# headless JRE is enough for Jenkins 
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

# or with JAVA 11
$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

### Maintain multible Java version in Ubuntu

The this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions) on howto maintain multible Java versions.

### Install Jenkins (as Debian package from jenkins.io)

There is some very easy [documentation](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/) on how to install the upstream jenkins Debian packages.

```
$ wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add
$ sudo bash -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

That should do the trick.

### Remove Jenkins

If you are using a packages based Jenkins installation, remove the package with:

```
$ sudo apt remove jenkins
```

If you are using the tarball from the Jenkins site, just delete the folder where you installed it.

Comment: Thanks Simon for taking time to answer. please see the java install command and the output i got. When searched for Java using command "which Java" nothing is displaying.

Comment: im not able to attach the screenshot of command and the output of it here. please let me know how can i do it?

Comment: sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  daemon net-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  openjdk-8-demo openjdk-8-source visualvm
The following NEW packages will be installed:

Comment: openjdk-8-jdk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,435 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,538 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jdk:amd64.
(Reading database ... 168837 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jdk:amd64 (8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-8-jdk:amd64 (8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...

Comment: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in auto mode

Comment: when i entered "which java" nothing is displayed. /usr/bin doesnt have java. /usr/lib/jvm has java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin but there is no java there...please help me understand this.

Comment: when i entered "whereis java" i got the /usr/share/java folder which has the following jars present gettext.jar           java_defaults.mk  juh-6.0.7.jar  jurt-6.0.7.jar  libintl.jar     ridl.jar             unoloader.jar
java-atk-wrapper.jar  java_uno.jar      juh.jar        jurt.jar        ridl-6.0.7.jar  unoloader-6.0.7.jar

Comment: I tried the following as well..sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-8-jre-headless is already the newest version (8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  daemon libice-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev net-tools
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev

Comment: Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.

Comment: still no use..im not able to find java.."which java" returns nothing.."java -version" returns following....Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Comment: @user7501425 Please add you comments to your question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1139046/edit). It is close to impossible to recover the output from the comment section

Comment: thanks Simon.                                                                                                        
1)i removed the openjdk-8-jre-headless and re-installed again..very strange..now its installed properly and "which java" is returning /usr/bin/java..i am confused why its working now.                                                                    
2)Should i install openjdk-8-jdk also along with this openjdk-8-jre-headless to run jenkins properly or someother software? or JRE is enough? please advice

Comment: no, the headless version is enough for Jenkins. Just start Jenkins at check if is is running properly

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins requires Java 8 jdk to be installed.
Check your java version by command
$ java -version
If you have more than one java installed on your machine
use the command
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
This will provide a list of java versions on your machines.
Use the comands to install jenkins
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install jenkins

To change the port number to say 9090 please  edit using sudo
$ sudo vim /etc/default/jenkins
8080 is the most commonly used port
Find 8080 and change to 9090
Save the file using :wq for Vim editor
Open browser
http://localhost:9090 to start config of jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after upgrading java from 8 to 11; because I had manually upgraded my jenkins on ubuntu by swapping in the new war. So, my old install had persisted the `/etc/init.d/jenkins` file with the bug.

For me the fix was as simple as running the proper apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade jenkins
```

Which properly replaced all the files to the latest version