# `apt-get install` without running `update-alternatives` (or specifying own priority)

Tags: apt, update-alternatives

Is there a way to install a package using `apt-get install` without `update-alternatives` being invoked? Or at least being able to specify your own custom priority for the new links added by `update-alternatives`?

In my scenario I want to install multiple JDK versions. JDK 11 is (while writing this) LTS so I would prefer if all links used that.
However the issue is that apparently the `update-alternatives` priority for the JDK packages is based on the version:

- `openjdk-11-jdk-headless`: 1111
- `openjdk-13-jdk-headless`: 1311
- `openjdk-14-jdk-headless`: 1411

So if I additionally install JDK 13 or 14 all links would use that as first choice instead.

While I could use `update-alternatives --config` to change to "manual mode", this seems tedious because it appears this has to be done for every link on its own (JDK 14 adds 33 links) and error-prone in case a new binary is added in a future version, but does not exist in an older one.

Comment: "this has to be done for every link on its own";  did you take a look at `update-java-alternatives`?

Comment: @danzel, no I was not aware that it exists, thanks for pointing that out. Do you want to add that as answer? Though doesn't the problem described in the question also affect other packages, and do they all have their own `update-X-alternatives` then?

Comment: If your question was how to switch between Java versions, it'd be a duplicate of the question I answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/740782/354663). However, your question is more about preventing `apt-get` from configuring debian alternatives which I don't know how to do but hopefully someone else does. So even if your original problem is solved, I'd like to leave this question unanswered for people interested in an answer.

Comment: @danzel, yes that was my question. It would still be interesting to know whether there is a general solution (applying to all packages and not just Java) to this problem. But I guess this question here could be closed as duplicate.