# Install Java 6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, java

I need to install Java 6 on Ubuntu. I downloaded `jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin` and extracted it here.

```
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
java-11-openjdk-amd64      java-6-oracle             openjdk-11
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:/usr/lib/jvm$
```

But how can I tell Ubuntu that I want to use `java-6-oracle`?

Comment: Have a look a this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions

Comment: @PiotrG Sorry. I have tried that.

Comment: You can always set JAVA_HOME and use an explicit path to the Java executable. Java6 is out of sevrice since 2013 and totally EOL since 2018. My personal experience is that backwards compatibility in Java releases is good, and there is less risk to run a java6-era app in Java8 or 11 that to try to run a Java6 JVM on modern hardware/OS (and with modern hackers)

Comment: @xenoid I solved this by installing Java 8. I was in need of Swing. Java 11 don't have Swing :(