# Have to manually restart Network Manager through command line every time the system starts

Tags: networking

Newbie here. I have an 'antenna' that I plug into my computer to pick up a far-flung wifi signal and it works brilliantly.  I can boot up, plug in and connect without a problem.  The trouble is, now, when I bring my computer to a cafe (for example) I have to open the command line and type:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

this works fine and away I go.  How can I set it so I don't have to type this at all?  What did I change by plugging my antenna in?

I should mention I have Ubuntu Studio 16.04.

Comment: Just a reminder, 16.10 is out of support. You should use 17.04 or any of the supported LTS versions (14.04 & 16.04).

Comment: You may [create a permanent short alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias/17538#17538) to avoid typing the whole thing all the time.

Comment: Thanks Pomsky.  Just for clarification and so I don't go typing random things into Gedit...  So I think I should type


export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
alias sudo service network-manager restart='sudo service network-manager restart'

Is that right?  Seems not quite right. but what would I be typing and what will the desired effect be?   Thanks again  also... how do I put coding into those nifty quotes?

Comment: Try something simpler. Open the `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory. It's hidden file, so you'll have to enable **show hidden files and folders** in file manager first. Then type the following line in the file: `alias ntwrkrstrt='sudo service network-manager restart'` and save the file. Instead of `ntwrkrstrt` you may use any other short memorable string, just make sure it's not same as any existing command. Then you won't have to type the whole thing in Terminal all the time, typing this short string will do the same.

Comment: Thanks so much pomsky!  That's a great short cut.  Now, is there a way that I don't have to type anything and it just starts right up with the computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)