# How do I quit top without leaving the output on the terminal?

Tags: command-line, top

How do I get `top` to quit similarly to the way `less` quits, that is, not leaving behind its output on the screen?

This is the version I have:

```
procps-ng version 3.3.9
```

Comment: How about using an alternative, like `htop`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you start it like this ...

```
top && clear
```

... the screen clears after exiting top with q.

This acts more like `less`:

```
tput smcup ; top ; tput rmcup
```

(`smcup` switches to a secondary screen where the `top` command is executed and when you quit `top` `rmcup` switches back to the normal screen)

---

You could alias the top command to do that ( [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) )

Comment: `clear` seems to erase all but the last screen of the scrollback buffer too (so just leaving top's last screen in this case) - at least in xfce4-terminal and QTerminal. The `tput` answer works great, especially in an alias for `top`

Comment: Don't forget Ctl+L for a quick-fix.

Comment: Oh, interesting; I was wondering why `less`'s last output completely disappeared from the buffer.

Comment: Some other suggestions: 1. use the far-superior-but-not-built-in `htop`, and 2. alias the commands together so you don't have to manually chain them each time.

Comment: @flith I am not going to steal the other users answers ;-)

Answer (score 31):

Ironically<sup>1</sup>, this was *briefly* the behaviour of `top`. In 3.3.8, `top` did clear the screen, but not in versions past or since. See [Red Hat bug #977561](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=977561#c3):

> The screen clearing is an indirect result of changes in terminal
>   manipulations which were introduced by Jim Warner (author of the 'top'
>   tool) in order to suppress flooding the 'top' tool with SIGWINCH
>   signals generated by some of the widely used terminal applications. It
>   was me who reported the flooding issue and he tried to do his best in
>   order to resolve it and released a fix for the issue in form of 8
>   separate commits. The commit introducing the screen clearing has the
>   following hash : 'dedaf6e1a81738ff08ee8e8523871e12f555ad6d'.

Due to the bug report, Jim then fixed it to again [not clear the output in 3.3.9](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/NEWS#L124).

`top` has no options or configuration settings to control this, AFAICT, this is entirely hardcoded behaviour. You might want to file a feature request at https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/.

Until then, you could `clear` manually like [Rinzwind suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012738/158442), or use `tput` like steeldriver suggests.

---

Interestingly, [the commit mentioned above](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/dedaf6e1a81738ff08ee8e8523871e12f555ad6d) also has a nice explanation of the command steeldriver suggested, because it is in fact the same as what was originally done in the code:

> A scrollback buffer used in several terminal emulators could be a real
>   inconvenience to a user following some resize operations. Extra
>   keystroke(s) would frequently be required in order to properly render
>   top's display.
>
> After much sleuthing we unearthed two terminfo strings which have the
>   effect of disabling/restoring that darn scrollback buffer. They were
>   well hidden under a title of strings 'to start/end programs using
>   cup'. In turn, 'cup' deals with a tty's cursor addressing capability.
>
> We don't care what you call them or what they refer to so long as they
>   get the job done. And these really do! Be advised, however, that there
>   are some side effects, several of which can even be considered as
>   beneficial:
>
> - enter_ca_mode/smcup/ti disables scrollback buffering ( and that's
>     good, it's what we had always hoped for )
> - exit_ca_mode/rmcup/te restores the scrollback buffer ( but also
>     restores screen contents existing pre-top ) ( which is different from
>     former program end results ) ( where that last rendered screen was
>     left untouched )

... which corresponds to the `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup` commands.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Obligatory xkcd.](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: Interestingly BSD top (e.g. on MacOS) also does clear the terminal

Answer (score 15):

The behavior you are looking for from less is built in to an alternative called htop. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Specifically, it switching to the alternate screen mode before starting preserving your original screen contents when you close htop. It also has a variety of other enhancements over procps's top. Once it's installed, you can just run it as a regular user:

```
htop
```

Comment: Plus `htop` is very colourful, adds mouse support, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `watch`:

```
watch top -b
```

It default to update every two seconds, use e.g. `-n1` for one second if you want to change this behaviour. To quit `watch`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of the usual <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Another approach is opening a new terminal window, e.g. with `xterm`:

```
xterm -e top
```

This behaves exactly like `top` normally does, the window closes when you quit `top` with <kbd>Q</kbd> and of course it leaves no output in the terminal you started it from. Add `&` to the end of this command to start it in the background and immediately release the terminal again.

Answer (score 1):

As Rinzwind's answer points out, the `clear` command clears `top` output from the screen.

After exiting `top` you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the `top` output from the screen. After either command though, you can still scroll up the screen to see the old `top` output.

To really clear the screen, such that the `top` output cannot be scrolled back to, use the `reset` command:

```
top && reset
```

---

Another option to give that "fresh look" of a brand new session is by running an "ASCII splash screen" (if you have one). In my case I would run:

```
top && reset && now && screenfetch
```

[image: reset now splash.png]

- My `now` script calls weather, calendar (`cal`) and `toilet` with fancy time.
- `screenfetch` paints the Ubuntu logo and machine stats.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend re-running `.bashrc` _regularly_ without need because usually there are lines like `export PATH=...:$PATH` in that file and running it multiple times will unnecessarily extend the `PATH`. Also, calling `neofetch` in `.bashrc` is not standard behaviour (although it looks fancy). For instance, when I re-run my `.bashrc` nothing apparent happens.

Comment: CTRL+L and `clear` behave _not_ the same: try `for i in {1..200}; do echo "line $i"; done` in two different, fresh windows. Then hit `CTRL+L` in window1 and type `clear` in window2. Now scroll back in both windows (mouse wheel). In the `CTRL+L`-window you can see all lines (depending on your scroll buffer) while in the `clear`-window you can only scroll back _one_ screen. That is: `clear` clears the scrollback buffer while `CTRL+L` is similar to $window_height times pressing `ENTER` (aka newline).

Comment: @PerlDuck `neofetch` is a good catch but it's a derivative I guess called `screenfetch`. I use it to remind myself I'm in Ubuntu because I have dual boot and Windows Bash has a different splash screen. I'll take out `.bashrc` reference. As for `clear` and `Ctrl`+`L` my point was they are similar in that they both leave `top` output in scroll back buffer.

Comment: I think everybody has different things in their `.bashrc`. Try `curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0`, it's awesome. Use `curl wttr.in/:help` to get help. I have a similar call in a `/etc/update-motd.d/` scriptlet so I get informed when logging in from console or ssh (not for every terminal window). If you like that, add `--silent --max-time 3` to the curl call so it won't take forever if internet is slow.

Comment: @PerlDuck The `curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0` is AWESOME! Thank you so much. I'll try to squeeze that in after the `toilet` time display on my splash screen :)

Comment: You are welcome. And I _knew_ you would love it. ;-) So did I when I saw it the first time.

Comment: @PerlDuck After a [programming glitch was fixed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013954/bash-substring-stringoffsetlength-error/1013960#1013960) I managed to get the weather embedded in the splash screen (show above). And *you* were right I do love it :)

Comment: Love the MOTD, BTW!  =)  Just noting here with my system that with the `reset` and `clear` commands it all depends on the terminal I happen to be using.  In `gnome-terminal` when I use clear it does clear the last page, and if I run it a couple of more times I end up with a blank scroll back page is all.  `xfce4-terminal` on the other hand keeps all my  scroll back buffers and keeps adding in a blank scroll back page.  The `reset` command on the other hand seems universal in the terminals that it clears all the scroll back.

Comment: @Terrance On vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 / Unity `Ctrl`+`L` clears the screen but you can still scroll back. The `clear` command also allow scroll back to the `top` command output but everything before that is erased from the scroll buffer.

Comment: @PerlDuck I published the weather script but can I ask how you change the city name from Edmonton?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-gnome-terminal-splash-screen/1020693#1020693 For example `Paris, USA` would have dozens of  hits.