# `cal -h` command: Bash substring `${string:offset:length}` error

Tags: bash

## Beware the Ides of March Caesar

I'm getting a weird error in bash using: `${string:offset:length}`.

The fifth output line for the middle of March has the wrong output:

```
$ substring_test.sh
     March 2018       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  T=   T=   T=   T=   T= 1 T= 2 T= 3 
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  T= 4 T= 5 T= 6 T= 7 T= 8 T= 9 T=10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  T= T= T= 1 T= 1 T= 1 T= 1 T= 1 
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  T=18 T=19 T=20 T=21 T=22 T=23 T=24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 31  T=25 T=26 T=27 T=28 T=29 T=30 T=31 
                      T=   T=   T=   T=   T=   T=   T=
```

It is showing:

```
T= T= T= 1 T= 1 T= 1 T= 1 T= 1
```

But it **should** show:

```
T=11 T=12 T=13 T=14 T=15 T=16 T=17
```

The code is pretty straight forward:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cal > /tmp/terminal

CalLineCnt=1
Today=$(date +"%d")

# Prefix with space when length < 2
if [[ ${#Today} < 2 ]] ; then
    Today=" "$Today
fi

while IFS= read -r Cal; do
    printf "$Cal"
    if [[ $CalLineCnt > 2 ]] ; then
        # See if today is on current line & invert background
        for (( j=0 ; j <= 18 ; j += 3 )) ; do
            Test=${Cal:$j:2}    # Current day on calendar line
printf "T=$Test "
            if [[ "$Test" == "$Today" ]] ; then
                printf "Offset: $j "
            fi
        done
    fi
    tput cud1           # Down one line
    CalLineCnt=$((++CalLineCnt))
done < /tmp/terminal
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

## End Result

Applying fix of `cal -h` recommended below it worked fine until **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** was released and tested on April 28, 2018. Now the fix recommended by @Steve H is used:

[image: now.png]

Some are curious about the what the code does so I provided the screen shot above. Others have asked for the full code and it is available here:[How can I get this terminal splash screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-screen)

Comment: You might want to make an MCVE

Comment: @wjandrea MCVE=Move Computer Violently Elsewhere?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you just let `cal` do the highlighting and instead do something like `echo $weather; cal`?

Comment: @NicHartley I updated the question with a snapshot after the problem was fixed. Before inserting the weather, `cal` was simply called with no need to highlight the day manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that `cal` is already highlighting the current day, and the control codes are throwing off the offsets

Look at `/tmp/terminal` in a hex editor.  Today (the 11th) is: `5F 08 31 5F 08 31`, and not `31 31`

Use `cal -h` to switch off the auto highlighting of today's date.

Comment: I regret to report that `cal -h` no longer works with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I've had to switch code to @Steve H answer below.

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Thornton would be OK if all implementations of cal actually recognised the -h as switching off formatting. Debian doesn't even though man suggests it does. It displays the usage instead.
So this would work.

```
cal > /tmp/terminal1
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40\60-\136\140-\176' < /tmp/terminal1  > /tmp/terminal
```

The file gets the cal output with formatting and the next line removes anything we don't want and lets the rest of the code do its work.

Comment: I performed tests with **Ubuntu 18.04** and `cal -h` is no longer supported. Your solution to remove all formatting works. I've updated the script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-screen