# How to change the default version of python in ubuntu permanently

Tags: command-line, 18.04, python, python3, versions

The default version of python in my Ubuntu 18.04 is 2.7.
I've already used the command: 
`alias python=python3`

but it changes the python version temporarily, as soon as I close the terminal and re-opens it the version again changes to python 2.7.

Is there any permanent solution to this issue?

Comment: You could add that command to your `.bashrc` so it is executed as you login.

Comment: As mentioned in many, many previous posts, DON'T change the links to the various versions of python, It will break stuff that depends on specif versions.

Comment: @JacobVlijm changing the symlinks will break things, but I think aliases should be safe, since scripts can't use them. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this existing question about creating a bash alias permanently:

[How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Essentially you want to edit the file `~/.bashrc` and put that command somewhere (likely near the bottom) in there. The linked question is pretty old (2010) and mentions `gedit` but you don't have to use that text editor to modify the file, you can use whatever text editor you want.

Comment: Thank you sir!. This solved my issue but don't remove my question as it's different issue than the question you mentioned. It'll help someone else like me in future :)