# Is it possible to achieve autocomplete to predifined text in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I have started learning Ubuntu since 1 year..
During this 1 year period I typed a lot of these below texts in `gnome-terminal`

```
sudo -H nautilus /foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/
sudo -H gedit /foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4/
```

what i am trying to ask is,

Is there a way I can configure like if I
type `sn` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, Autocompletion to `sudo -H nautilus`
type `sg` <kbd>TAB</kbd>, Autocompletion to `sudo -H gedit`

***I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10 with `gnome-terminal`***

**Edit:** I am not looking to type `sn /foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4` or `sg /foo1/foo2/foo3/foo4`.
looking for sn <kbd>TAB</kbd> or sn <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see the text on terminal as `sudo -H nautilus`

Comment: Autocompletion is not done by the terminal emulator (e.g. gnome-terminal) but the shell (e.g. bash, zsh). Please modify the question accordingly, stating which shell you use.

Comment: Autocompletion is done on a character or partial string of a command. What you're asking is full conversion from `1` to a completely different string of text, so I'm 90% sure this is not possible. What I'd suggest is creating a function or alias. Function and alias names don't allow for numeric names, so use `sn` and `sg` for `sudo -H nautilus` and `sudo -H gedit` instead.

Comment: @PRATAP Please see the linked duplicate. The form would be either `sn(){ sudo -H nautilus "$@" ; }` or `function sn(){ sudo -H nautilus "$@" ;}` Of course the usage is `sn /path/to/directory`. Where to put those functions is explained in linked duplicate. I'll provide couple extra links in a minute

Comment: To me it sounds like you want text expansion. There is a [zsh plugin](https://github.com/willghatch/zsh-snippets/blob/master/README.md) that supposedly works as you described it, albeit not using TAB but any other keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @PRATAP I've posted an answer on the linked duplicate that outlines the essential steps. Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: @PRATAP Alright, I've reopened the post. Like I've mentioned it's 90% likely this is not possible ( or at least not in a simple way). One could use  a small hack: use `xdotool` to basically erase what user typed into the terminal, and overwrite that with the desired command, but it's only going to be available in GUI, and not always in terminal.

Comment: @PRATAP  You're welcome. I try to help however I can. Right now I have to leave the site, so I'll come back to this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can simply use aliases to achieve what you want. Just type the alias, then continue providing the arguments with tab completion.

If you need to effectively expand your alias before executing the command, then press the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. Thus, after you have typed the name of your abbreviation (= an alias), press that key combination to see the alias expanded.

See here on [how to create a permanent alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias).

Comment: I have added a link to an askubuntu question about creating a permanent alias. In particular, you see a section # some more ls aliasses. You could add your aliasses there.

Comment: Glad it worked! Indeed, it takes some studying before you grasp it, but once you got it, it is very easy.