# Add custom shortcut to the GNOME Terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I want to add my own shortcuts to the terminal. 
So you know like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> clears the terminal.

I would like to be able to execute the command in the current terminal using shortcut. So for example, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and `ls -l` executes, etc.

Is that possible?

Comment: your OS plz.....

Comment: Sorry, thought that was implicit, it's Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I could achieve this by the mix of

1. [Is it possible to achieve autocomplete to predifined text in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1128229/739431)
2. Custom Keyboard Shortcut
3. `xdotool`

#### Steps

1. Created a alias for `ls -l` as `ls` in `~/.bashrc` file:

   [image: screenshot]
2. To type ls and a key press of Enter, used `xdotool sleep 1 key l s Return` as a command for custom keyboard shortcut:

   [image: screenshot]
3. Result, when I press the shortcut key combo:

   [image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a bit of workaround, but I guess you cannot do any better, so thanks for the answer - it does what I needed. I've just changed `xdotool sleep 1 key l s Return` to `xdotool sleep 0.2 key l s Return`, so instead of `1` second it's `0.2` seconds - that way it works quickly.

Comment: yes it is (sleep value) always user prefered value and based on trails in some cases..