# How do I set an alias to a terminal line?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I want to easily set an alias `git-go` to this terminal line:

```
git commit -m "init "; git push; git status
```

So when I enter git-go this line should enter.

How can I do that? The answers I seen only cover alias of a command without parameters. But I want to set an alias to an arbitrary terminal line.

**Edit:**
[I've learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943813/1308453) to use functions instead of aliases because

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
> confusing.

and

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

So don't use an alias unless you have to.
https://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

Comment: What did you try? Which other questions did you read? https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/507051 explains it quite good, what exactly is your question?

Comment: My issue was using double quotes instead of single for the outside quotes.

Comment: You could as well do it the other way around using double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do this the same way you would set any alias.

```bash
alias git-go='git commit -m "init "; git push; git status'
```

The situation where it gets tricky is *not* when an alias runs a command and passes arguments to that command, nor even when an alias runs multiple commands separated by `;`, but instead is when you want an alias to accept and use its own command-line arguments.

For example, anything you write *after* the name of that alias will be pasted onto the end, and thus passed as command-line arguments to the third `git` command, after `git status`. (Really it's not so much that the following text is pasted onto the end, as much as it is that the following text is left alone and the alias name is replaced with its definition.)

So you can run your alias without arguments, which works, and the last command is `git status`:

```bash
git-go
```

Or you can run it with arguments that you want passed to `git status`. For example, when you run it this way, the last command is `git-status --show-stash`:

```bash
git-go --show-stash
```

What you *cannot* do with an alias in Bash (and other Bourne-style shells) is to make the alias accept command-line arguments and place them elsewhere than the end.

For example, suppose you wanted `git-go` to accept an argument that it uses for the commit message. You would not be able to write this as an alias. The solution would be to write it as a shell function instead:

```bash
git-go() { git commit -m "$1"; git push; git status; }
```

In the definition of a shell function, the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, and so forth hold the values of the command-line arguments passed to the shell function. Aliases have no functionality that corresponds to this, because alias expansion is really a form of macro processing, taking place very early, when the shell parses a command.

You can, of course, write it as a shell function even if you don't need to use positional parameters in the definition, as [Videonauth suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152384/22949).

Comment: Even better: place a script named `git-go` in your PATH and `git go` will work.

Comment: Not true btw, you can create a function inside an alias to use arguments that are not at the end: `alias git-go='_git-go() { git commit "$@"; git push; git status; }; _git-go`, then you can run `git-go -m "my commit message"` or add any other arguments possible for `git commit`

Answer (score 10):

You can declare it a function in your `~/.bash_aliases` file like so:

```
git-go(){
    git commit -m "init "
    git push
    git status
}
```

or you can create an alias in the same file like so:

```
alias git-go='git commit -m "init "; git push; git status'
```

Do not forget to reopen your terminal or source the file (`. ~/.bash_aliases`) after you changed it.

Comment: One benefit of writing a shell function instead of an alias is that one needn't nest quotes. This answer thus addresses [the central problem the OP turned out to be having](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152381/how-do-i-set-an-alias-to-a-terminal-line#comment1916200_1152381) more directly than mine does.

Comment: @EliahKagan Both are fine for that question although yours is more throughout. Nice to see you back.

Answer (score 4):

As you are dealing with `git` commands, you might also want to know the
syntax for adding an alias especially for `git`:

```
git config --global alias.go '!sh -c "git commit -m \"init\"; git push; git status"'
```

This will add a new alias to your local `git` configuration (at `~/.gitconfig`) and allow
you to issue

```
git go
```

when inside a `git` repository. Whenever you run `git go` a shell is invoked and
the command `git commit -m "init"; git push; git status` is passed to it.

See [the git documentaion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias) 
for further details.

Answer (score 3):

It was a quoting problem. I had tried this:

```
alias="git commit -m "init "; git push; git status"
```

But got this error:

```
bash: ; git push; git status: command not found
```

I got that error because I was using nested quotes incorrectly. Here's the correct syntax:

```
alias='git commit -m "init "; git push; git status'
```

Or:

```
alias="git commit -m 'init '; git push; git status"
```

Or without quotes if no white space in the commit message:

```
alias="git commit -m init; git push; git status"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer (as my answer and Videonauth's don't focus much on the quoting issue). Out of curiosity, why did you want a trailing space in your commit messages?

Comment: I used to manually paste this line and I'd add a message after the space, but that doesn't make sense here so I took it out.

Comment: In that case, you needn't quote `init`; the shell treats `'init'`, `"init"`, and `init` the same. (So you may want to put back the original version and also show the new version, to illustrate the situation where nested quotes are needed.) As for being able to add the rest of the message, you could pass that as a command-line argument if (as shown in Videonauth's and my answers) you defined a function instead of an alias. For example, you could define `git-go() { git commit -m "init $1"; git push; git status; }` (which is what I have in my answer but with `"init $1"` instead of just `"$1"`).

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted to try next.