# trying to make bash alias on mac

Tags: bash, mac, alias

I am trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) explanation of how to make an alias and made the following .bashrc file in my home directory. Here it is:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions
alias py='python3'
alias pip='pip3'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew
export PATH
```

I restarted my shell and ran "py" and got a "command not found" error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

I tried the following as well:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions
alias py='/usr/bin/python3'
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip3'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew
export PATH
```

as well as:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions
alias py='/usr/local/bin/python3'
alias pip='/usr/local/bin/pip3'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/homebrew
export PATH
```

Both of these also gave a "command not found" error.

Comment: type in a termnial `whereis python3` then read the full path of the binary and provide this full path to your alias

Comment: thanks for this, I tried your recommendation of using the full path but as you can see in my latest edit, neither of the paths given when I did 'whereis' and 'which' worked

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3` give you.

Comment: I get this when I run that command:      `lrwxr-xr-x  1 mathewlewis  admin  34 14 May 02:37 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.7/bin/python3`