# How to set memory usage sort in top command as default?

Tags: command-line, ram, default, top, sort

I want to sort the memory usage in top command as default. So that i do not have to sort in every i run top command.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start it with

```
top -o %MEM
```

You can create an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias): `alias top='top -o %MEM'` in `~/.bashrc`) for this.

Easier method:  `top` can save to a configuration using `W`.

> **W :Write-the-Configuration-File** This will save all of your options and
> toggles plus the current display mode and delay time. By issuing this
> command just before quitting top, you will be able to restart later in
> exactly that same state.

It saves to `~/.toprc`. Going back to default is the same as removing `~/.toprc`.

Comment: Couldn't you specify the sort order in the config file?

Comment: Yep. Enter your command, press W to write the config file, next time `top` sorts by %MEM again.

Comment: Minor point: on my system, no backup file is created.

Comment: To be precise, no backup file is created on my 18.04 server or 20.04 laptop. On the laptop, the config file is written to `$HOME/.config/procops`.

Comment: Hmmm Ill remove it :( My server did but ... it is ehm older than we accept here :D

Comment: Thanks All... :)