# System doesn't remember alias

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, alias

Somewhat of a novice here. I recently installed the flatpak Brave browser and since it's tedious to write `flatpak run com.brave.Browser` every time to run it from the terminal, I tried to create an alias using `alias brave-browser="flatpak run com.brave.Browser"`. This works just fine for the instance, but when I open up a new terminal and type in the alias I get: `brave-browser: command not found`. This also happens with every other application I tried this with. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using the (default) `bash` shell in your terminal, then see [How do I create a permanent Bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear what I did wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an alias it will only function within that terminal.
You need to edit your `.bashrc` file which is in your home directory - add the alias to that file and it will be available on an ongoing basis (you'll need the terminal to 'read' the `.bashrc` file once you've edited the file - either close the terminal and open another (which will read the file), or type `. .bashrc` to force bash to read it.

There are a number of simple text editors - I use nano as it's very simple.

Make a copy of .bashrc in case you mess it up (eg `cp .bashrc .bashrc-backup`)

Then type `nano .bashrc`

You can then find a bit of the file with some aliases and add yours as a new line under some of the others (you can put it anywhere within the file but for human readability / order it is sensible to place it near other aliases).

Then save the file ('write out') by `Ctrl` + `o`
Then exit with `Ctrl` + `x`

If you mess it up, delete the damaged version (`rm .bashrc`) and restore it from your backup: you do that by 'moving' the file from its current location to the same location with a new name (`mv .bashrc-backup .bashrc`)

Of course, if you have a preferred text editor use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now!

Comment: As a small tip, nano will also save directly (without prompt) with Ctrl+S. So Ctrl+S Ctrl+X is the quick way to exit while saving the file. This is the perfect answer for the question as asked, but for flatpaks, I would rather install a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` that points to `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/com.brave.Browser`