How to create custom command mapped to dotnet console application
On ubuntu machine I create a C# dotnet console project myapp and publish it as a self contained application. It creates a new build and pushes to a directory.
Now I can simply cd to the directory where it is published and run from bash ./myapp "arg1"
I wonder how do I make my own global linux command so that it will be executed from anywhere without cding to the directory.
e.g. I ssh to my ubuntu and execute my custom command
myapp "arg1"


Anothe option, if you don't want to add the directory to PATH, would be to create an alias for the command /full/path/to/myapp "arg1": https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias
