# How do I get spaces instead of tabs in nano?

Tags: command-line, nano

I usually edit Python files with nano, so I need four spaces instead of a tab. How can I get nano to automatically insert spaces for tabs, and control how many of them it inserts?

Comment: StackOverflow: [tabs to spaces in nano](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15364505/1167012)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [nano Command Manual](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nano.html):

> **`-E, --tabstospaces`**
>   `Convert typed tabs to spaces.`
>
> **`-T <#cols>, --tabsize=<#cols>`**
>   `Set the displayed tab length to #cols columns. The value of #cols must be greater than 0. The default value is 8.`

For four spaces, the appropriate command would therefore be `nano -ET4`.

Consider [creating a permanent *alias*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias).

Comment: you could also consider editing `/etc/nanorc` instead of making an alias.

Comment: I feel like patching /etc/nanorc.... and uploading to fix this once and for all. With python3 not accepting mixed tabs&spaces this is silly to have tabs in python files in nano.

Answer (score 49):

Either create `.nanorc` in your home folder, including:

```
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
```

or edit the system `/etc/nanorc` file.