# In Nano is there a way to have nanorc settings apply to just one filetype/syntax?

Tags: text-editor, nano, syntax-highlighting

**Background:** To enable Nano's syntax highlighting I have configured various shared `.nanorc` files with the format `/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc`, eg `/usr/share/nano/python.nanorc`

This works well but I keep running into issues with Python where I would like it to convert tabs to spaces.

That setting is available ([How do I get spaces instead of tabs in nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40732/how-do-i-get-spaces-instead-of-tabs-in-nano)) with `set tabstospaces`, but it seems it has to be global.

**Q. Is there a way to have this setting apply only on Python files?**

I tried to move `set tabstospaces` to the relevant `nanorc` file, `python.nanorc` mentioned above. However when I try this I get an error upon saving the file in Nano indicating that I can't do this because included files cannot contain set:

```
Error in /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc on line 42: Command "set" not allowed in included file
```

Perhaps this is simply a nano limitation and I have to set it only at the global level, but it would be ideal if it could be per syntax.  It's not the biggest disaster as Nano is not my main text editor for code but it often convenient for something small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabgives "    "` command *in a syntax highlight file* to override global `tabstospaces` setting for a given file type.

From [`man 5 nanorc`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html):

> **tabgives** "*string*"
>
> Make the `<Tab>` key produce the given *string*. Useful for languages like Python that want to see only spaces for indentation. This overrides the setting of the **tabstospaces** option.