# How can I encode and decode percent-encoded strings on the command line?

Tags: command-line, conversion, text, encoding, url

How can I encode and decode [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (URL encoded) strings on the command line?

I'm looking for a solution that can do this:

```
$ percent-encode "ændrük"
%C3%A6ndr%C3%BCk
$ percent-decode "%C3%A6ndr%C3%BCk"
ændrük
```

Comment: Do you want to incorporate different encodings too? `%E6ndr%FCk` doesn't look like (standard) UTF8 to me. Or it's just an example?

Comment: @arrange Thanks for catching that. Apparently I chose the [bad apple](http://urldecoder.waraxe.us/) among search results for online converters.

Comment: For file names, see: [How to remove URI encoding in file names](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76500/how-to-remove-uri-encoding-in-file-names).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

These commands do what you want (using Python 2):

```
python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1])" æ
python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])" %C3%A6
```

If you want to encode spaces as `+`, replace `urllib.quote` with `urllib.quote_plus`.

I'm guessing you will want to [alias them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) ;-)

Comment: What is that æ character at the end of first line? Edit: answering to myself - got it, it's just a single character UTF8 to-be-encoded string for example purpose :-)

Comment: how about python3?

Comment: @RicardoE check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110641/349837).

Answer (score 38):

#### shell

Try the following command line:

```
$ echo "%C3%A6ndr%C3%BCk" | sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g' | xargs -0 printf "%b"
ændrük
```

---

You may define it as alias and add it to your shell *rc* files:

```
$ alias urldecode='sed "s@+@ @g;s@%@\\\\x@g" | xargs -0 printf "%b"'
```

Then every time when you need it, simply go with:

```
$ echo "http%3A%2F%2Fwww" | urldecode
http://www
```

---

#### bash

When scripting, you can use the following syntax:

```
input="http%3A%2F%2Fwww"
decoded=$(printf '%b' "${input//%/\\x}")
```

<sup>However above syntax won't handle pluses (`+`) correctly, so you've to replace them with spaces via `sed`.</sup>

You can also use the following `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` functions:

```bsh
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c"
        esac
    done
}

urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string>

    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}
```

> Note that your urldecode() assumes the data contains no backslash.

---

#### bash + xxd

Bash function with `xxd` tool:

```bsh
urlencode() {
  local length="${#1}"
  for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
    local c="${1:i:1}"
    case $c in
      [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
    *) printf "$c" | xxd -p -c1 | while read x;do printf "%%%s" "$x";done
  esac
done
}
```

Found in [cdown's gist file](https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649), also at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250698/shell-script-to-urldecode-file-contents).

---

#### Python

Try to define the following aliases:

```
alias urldecode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
alias urlencode='python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])"'
```

Usage:

```
$ urlencode "ændrük"
C%26ndrC%3Ck
$ urldecode "%C3%A6ndr%C3%BCk"
ændrük
```

<sup>Source: [ruslanspivak](http://web.archive.org/web/20130806071526/http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/06/02/urlencode-and-urldecode-from-a-command-line/)</sup>

---

#### PHP

Using PHP you can try the following command:

```
$ echo oil+and+gas | php -r 'echo urldecode(fgets(STDIN));' // Or: php://stdin
oil and gas
```

or just:

```
php -r 'echo urldecode("oil+and+gas");'
```

Use `-R` for multiple line input.

---

#### Perl

In Perl you can use [`URI::Escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3A%3AEscape).

```
decoded_url=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' "$encoded_url")
```

Or to process a file:

```
perl -i -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape($ARGV[0])' file
```

---

#### sed

Using `sed` can be achieved by:

```
cat file | sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' | xargs echo -e
```

---

#### awk

Try [anon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000368/55075) solution:

```
awk -niord '{printf RT?$0chr("0x"substr(RT,2)):$0}' RS=%..
```

See: [Using awk printf to urldecode text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728049/using-awk-printf-to-urldecode-text).

---

#### decoding file names

If you need to remove url encoding from the file names, use `deurlname` tool from `renameutils` (e.g. `deurlname *.*`).

See also:

- [Can wget decode uri file names when downloading in batch?](https://superuser.com/questions/783337/can-wget-decode-uri-file-names-when-downloading-in-batch)
- [How to remove URI encoding from file names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76500/how-to-remove-uri-encoding-in-file-names)

---

Related:

- [How to decode URL-encoded string in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250698/how-to-decode-url-encoded-string-in-shell) at SO
- [Decoding URL encoding (percent encoding)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159253/decoding-url-encoding-percent-encoding) at unix SE

Comment: The bash + xxd version does not work with strings that contain a `%`, maybe you could replace `printf "$c"` with `printf "%c" "$c"`? A other problem is that some non-ASCII charachters are not encoded (such as `ä`) in some language settings, maybe add a `export LC_ALL=C` in the function (that should not affect anything outside the function)?

Answer (score 10):

#### Percent-encode reserved URI characters and non-ASCII characters

```
jq -s -R -r @uri
```

`-s` (`--slurp`) reads input lines into an array and `-s -R` (`--slurp --raw-input`) reads the input into a single string. `-r` (`--raw-output`) outputs the contents of strings instead of JSON string literals.

#### Percent-encode all characters

```
xxd -p|tr -d \\n|sed 's/../%&/g'
```

`tr -d \\n` removes the linefeeds that are added by `xxd -p` after every 60 characters.

#### Percent-encode all characters except ASCII alphanumeric characters in Bash

```bsh
eu () {
    local LC_ALL=C c
    while IFS= read -r -n1 -d '' c
    do 
        if [[ $c = [[:alnum:]] ]]
        then 
            printf %s "$c"
        else
            printf %%%02x "'$c"
        fi
    done
}
```

Without `-d ''` this would skip linefeeds and null bytes. Without `IFS=` this would replace characters in `IFS` with `%00`. Without `LC_ALL=C` this would for example replace `あ` with `%3042` in a UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 9):

Pure bash solution *for decoding only*:

```
$ a='%C3%A6ndr%C3%BCk'
$ echo -e "${a//%/\\x}"
ændrük
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to [Stefano ansqer](https://askubuntu.com/a/53783/349837) but in Python 3:

```sh
python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote(sys.argv[1]))" æ         # to percent-enconding
python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.argv[1]))" %C3%A6  # from percent-enconding
```

To encode also slashes:

```sh
python3 -c "import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1], \"\"))"
```

More info about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31827113/4970442).

Comment: For folks in 2022, that's the only version that works lol

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment on [best answer in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/53783/85721), so here is mine.

Personally, I use these aliases for URL encoding and decoding:

```
alias urlencode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(  sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1])"'

alias urldecode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1])"'
```

Both commands allow you to convert data, passed as a **command line argument** or read it from **standard input**, because both one-liners check whether there are command line arguments (even empty ones) and process them or just read standard input otherwise.

### update 2015-07-16 (empty 1st arg)

... according to @muru comment.

### update 2017-05-28 (slash encoding)

If you also need to encode the slash, just add an empty second argument to the quote function, then the slash will also be encoded.

So, finally `urlencode` *alias* in *bash* looks like this:

```
alias urlencode='python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1], \"\")"'
```

### Example

```
$ urlencode "Проба пера/Pen test"
%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test

$ echo "Проба пера/Pen test" | urlencode
%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test

$ urldecode %D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test
Проба пера/Pen test

$ echo "%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%2FPen%20test" | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test

$ urlencode "Проба пера/Pen test" | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test

$ echo "Проба пера/Pen test" | urlencode | urldecode
Проба пера/Pen test
```

Comment: I think `sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1]` might be more appropriate. Especially if you use this in scripts and accidentally give an empty first argument.

Comment: As per @muru comment I changed the checking for an argument on the command line. It was:  

    `len(sys.argv) < 2 and sys.stdin.read()[0:-1] or sys.argv[1]`

Now:

    `sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else sys.stdin.read()[0:-1]`

That is, if there is even an empty first argument, the command does not wait for input from the standard input, but processes an empty argument.

Comment: `urldecode` is printing extra new lines in output. (python3.10)

Answer (score 2):

I found a package, `renameutils`, that contain the utility `deurlname` that is able to rename a file containing "percent-encoded" characters.

Unfortunately, it does not decode stdin or a command line option, but only rename a file, so you have to create a dummy file to obtain the decoding (the name of the renamed file), but with some bash scripting the process can be automated.

No information about the encoding part, even because it could be questionable which characters to encode. Only non-ASCII?

I think there should be some better tool/method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POSIX Awk function for encoding:

```js
function encodeURIComponent(str, j, q) {
  while (y++ < 125) z[sprintf("%c", y)] = y
  while (y = substr(str, ++j, 1))
    q = y ~ /[[:alnum:]_.!~*\47()-]/ ? q y : q sprintf("%%%02X", z[y])
  return q
}
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/sage/blob/84f8350/sage#L17-L22)