# Opening an archive as a folder in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, archive, file-roller

I'd like to open an archive (zip, 7z, rar, etc.) as a subfolder in Nautilus. That is, when I double-click an archive, I'd like it to open in the same Nautilus window instead of starting Archive Manager.

I saw various responses to this question, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270636/integration-of-archives-navigation-in-nautilus), but most are over five years old. There was also an 2016 OMG! UBUNTU! [article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/native-nautilus-file-extract-archive) that says that decompression would be incorporates from Archive Manager into Nautilus and "navigation through the compressed file like a normal folder would be possible". I am wondering what the situation in 2020 is.

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and GNOME 3.34.2.

Answer (score -1):

You should install `unrar` by the following command:

```bsh
sudo apt install unrar
```

Comment: I already have it installed.