# How to mount drive in /media/userName/ like nautilus does using udisks

Tags: nautilus, mount, automount, udisks

**Update:** Ubuntu 16.04+ includes a utility called `disks`; search it in dash. It's a GUI for mounting/handling disks. I'm using this tool for mounting or hiding drives.

---

In my current installation of Ubuntu 13.10 Unity, when I click on a drive in nautilus it gets mounted on `/media/username/mountedDrive`

I read that nautilus uses `udisks` to do that.
Basically I want to auto mount my drive using `udisks` in start up using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Adding_to_startup) method

The problem is, it mounts the drive in `/media/mountedDrive`, but I want it the way nautilus does in `/media/username/mountedDrive`

**I want my NTFS Data drive to be auto mounted at `/media/bsienn/`**

```
$ blkid

/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="8230744030743D6B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows 7" UUID="60100EA5100E81F0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="882C04092C03F14C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="8768800f-59e1-41a2-9092-c0a8cb60dabf" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Ubuntu Drive" UUID="13ea474a-fb27-4c91-bae7-c45690f88954" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="69c22e73-9f64-4b48-b854-7b121642cd5d" TYPE="ext4" 

$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19452 cylinders, total 312500000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8d528d52

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   117730069    58761611    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       158690072   312494116    76902022+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       117731326   158689279    20478977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       137263104   141260799     1998848   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       141262848   158689279     8713216   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       117731328   137263103     9765888   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

$ cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=69c22e73-9f64-4b48-b854-7b121642cd5d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=8768800f-59e1-41a2-9092-c0a8cb60dabf none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: @Bsienn: If have to create an entry to `/etc/fstab` of the partition you want to mount automatically during boot. You can mount at any place you want. But you've to provide the output of these commands: `sudo blkid`, `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Edit your question and post the output.

Comment: @Saurav Kumar thanks for reply, i'm very now to linux, just installed 3 days ago, so was scared to use fstab method. But it seems its the better way to do, then easy :) let me post back in 1 min :)

Comment: This seems complicated - check [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/517738/289138).

Comment: A very similar question (with many useful answers) is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342188/how-to-auto-mount-from-command-line).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see except for `/dev/sda5` as well as `/dev/sda7` there is no entry of other partitions in `/etc/fstab`. You can manually mount your partitions by following these steps.

- First of all **unmount** all partitions before creating an entry point to `/etc/fstab`. You can use command: `sudo umount /dev/sdaX`. Replace **X** with the partition number you want to unmount. Best way to unmount all is to use this command:

  ```
  sudo umount -a
  ```
- Since you want to mount your partition at `/media/user/mount-drive`; you have to create the mount-point where you want to mount the partitions. Thus you've to create directories there in order to mount the partitions. Execute following in terminal to make the directories(mount point):

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/user/sda1 /media/user/sda2 /media/user/sda3 /media/user/sda6
  ```

  Replace **`user`** with your ubuntu user's name. i,e **`bsienn`** I think.
- Now you have to make changes in `/etc/fstab` in order to mount your all partitions. Execute following commands to do so:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orginal
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```

  go to the last line and add these lines:

  ```
  UUID=8230744030743D6B /media/user/sda1    ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  UUID=60100EA5100E81F0 /media/user/sda2    ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  UUID=882C04092C03F14C /media/user/sda3    ntfs    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  UUID=13ea474a-fb27-4c91-bae7-c45690f88954 /media/user/sda6    ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  ```

  again replace **`user`** in `/media/user/sdaX` with your ubuntu account name.

  <sub>**A little explanation:** UUID="contains the ID of your hard disk partitions, 1st is of `/dev/sda1` and 2nd is of `/dev/sda2` partitions and so on. `sudo blkid` command is very useful to get the partitions information like **UUID**, **File-system type**, **partition entry** etc.. So any one can use it to get their information. `/media/user/sda1` is the mount entry of 1st partition and so on. Remember why I created 4 directories above. `ntfs` is the file system type of your 1st partition: `/dev/sda1`. It may be something else also like: `ext3`, `ext4`, `ntfs`, `fat` etc, you can get the info from `sudo blkid` command as I mentioned above. others will be same for all types of file-system, it tells that if any error occurs then `remount the file system in read-only mode` [this link](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/200709/page07.html) is a great tutorial.</sub>

  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit. Press <kbd>y</kbd> when prompt to save.
- Now mount all partitions by executing this command:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

  If you want to mount any specific partition you can use: `sudo mount /dev/sda1` i,e to mount first partition and so on.

Now all your partitions will be mounted automatically when ever you start your system. You can check it by restart your system. :)

Reply if you need further assistance or if something goes wrong.

**Edit**

I forgot to saw the picture, actually you can create the folder name under `/media/bseinn/` the name you want. For example `/media/bseinn/data` can be created instead of `/media/bseinn/sda3`; similarly `/media/bseinn/ubuntudrive` can be created instead of `/media/bseinn/sda6`. You've to give the same name in `/etc/fstab` file. Hope you can understand.

Comment: thanks for ur help, i'll try it in 30 mins. i was waiting and hoping for an email notification, but didn't got any, u replied within mins, my bad i didn't re checked sooner.

Comment: Thanks a lot Saurav, it works as desired. can u explain a bit on what these commands do: sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orginal
sudo nano /etc/fstab. is there any editor way to do this? gedit something?

Comment: I'm glad that you asked.. :) `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.original` will make a copy of original `/etc/fstab` file so that if any error occurs we will  always have a safe side :) `sudo nano /etc/fstab` means you're opening the file to edit in **nano** editor. nano is a simple and good editor, although you can use any other GUI editor like **gedit**. Hope you doubt is clear now! :)

Comment: Don't know if I should spam comments with THANKS, but for now, I'll. Thanks @Saurav Kumar

Comment: The last field (=`fs_passno`) in `/etc/fstab` should be `2` according to `man fstab`: `This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time.  The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.   Other  filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2. ...`

Comment: Strange, I'm able to use udisksctl to mount and umount disks with nothing added to fstab. Though I'm not booting from any of those disks, maybe that's the difference.

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer does not really answer the question, namely how to mount and unmount hard drives using udisks *like Nautilus does* when clicking on a disk. The command you are looking for is `udiskctl`.

**It's super easy, and also works with encrypted disks!**

### Mounting (encrypted disk):

Unlock the disk:

```
$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1
Unlocked /dev/sdb1 as /dev/dm-3.
```

Take note of the location of the unlocked device (here `/dev/dm-3`). Then mount it automatically:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/dm-3 
Mounted /dev/dm-3 at /media/jmiserez/samsung1000.
```

### Unmounting (encrypted disk):

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/dm-3
Unmounted /dev/dm-3.
$ udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdb1
Locked /dev/sdb1.
```

For unencrypted disks, just leave out the lock/unlock command in the beginning and end.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was absolute beginner and needed the things done. Now I Simply use `Disks` tools to mount the drives. super easy GUI way. Your answer is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulRehman thanks for that, the Disks GUI tool helps a lot and made locating my disk in the /dev folder much easier!

Answer (score 3):

Mount by label, without root password, with udisksctl and the label of the partition.
Example with a partition named Games:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/Games
```

Use `ls` to get the labels:

```
ls /dev/disk/by-label
```