# Prevent USB Drives from auto-remounting after remove

Tags: usb, automount

When I press "safely remove drive" in Nautilus as user to my USB 3.0 *Transcent Storejet 25H3* drive it reconnects immediately.

How can I safely remove it without that behaviour?

I think the only solution is to disable the automounting in Ubuntu. I did that now with:
[How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)

But it is a shame, cause now my external music library doesn't automount anymore.

Isn't there a solution where harddisks don't remount on safely remove?!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences

Comment: I've reopened the question. Please post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: To still have it automounted once at system start, you can add it to your. `/etc/fstab`, so the drive  will be auto mounted until you unmount it manually. 

Additionally, if you want to be sure, it even mounts if it failed to mount read-write (due to an unclean unmount in windows before) you can use this script to remount it readonly then: http://askubuntu.com/questions/424913/

Comment: bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085

Answer (score 5):

Valid for this Ubuntu at least:

```
$ lsb_release -d  
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

---

**I have found that:**

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/$device
```

... will mount /dev/xxx in the same style as automount,
that is - in `/media/$USER/Disk_Label-or-UUID/` with the last level dir auto-created.

```
$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/$device;
```

... will `umount` the above, but not '-eject' memory card/USB reader content.

```
$ gvfs-mount --eject "file:///media/$USER/DISK_LABEL"
```

... lastly appears to be equal to 'Safely remove' or 'Eject' - and that WITHOUT an immediate re-mount.

*Note:
    $ udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/$device;

... would otherwise be a 'natural' option, but is hampered by an immediate re-mount.*

---

*EDIT* --- you could use this script to "umount all" without having to dig out the names:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
for device in $(mount | grep "/media/$USER/" | cut -d" " -f1); do
        echo Unmounting $device 
        udisksctl unmount --block-device $device
done
```

if you prefer eject, change the `-f1` into `-f3` in the `cut` command and the line with `udiskctl` with

```
gvfs-mount --eject "file://$device"
```

(I think --- you can have problem with correctly quoting labels with blanks in it; and you'll have warnings if the device has multiple partitions mounted).

---

```
$ lsblk
```

... will display all the available block devices (except ram disks, **no sudo required**).
RAM and loop --> `lsblk --all` .

---

**How do I "automount" a labelled disk?**

Bring up the Dash (hit the 'Super' key) and type 'startup appl' and 'Startup Applications' should appear, click on it.
Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and type anything you want in 'Name' and 'Comment' fields. Then fill in 'Command' with your version of:

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/sleep 5 && /usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/GreenWD_3TB'
```

... where `/dev/disk/by-label/GreenWD_3TB` is anything suitable you find from
the display of `ls -lR /dev/disk/* | less`

---

More:
[How to access gvfs mounts from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232497/how-to-access-gvfs-mounts-from-command-line)
[How to mount drive in /media/userName/ like nautilus does using udisks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365052/how-to-mount-drive-in-media-username-like-nautilus-do-using-udisks)

Comment: `gvfs-mount --eject` doesn't work as "Safely Remove" for me on the same 14.04.1 LTS. It just unmouts and keeps harddisk spinning. `Error ejecting mount: Error ejecting /dev/sdc: Command-line 'eject "/dev/sdc"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: eject: unable to eject, last error: Invalid argument`. It seems a bug.

Comment: Please check above again; you cannot use `/dev/sdc` with gvfs-mount .

Comment: Yeah, I see, the error uses this way to mention the drive.

Comment: @Hannu I added a script to the answer --- I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Well, does not seem directly related to answering the Q - but might be useful for someone.